# Math.Pow vs multiply operator (performance)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, pow

Anyone knows if multiply operator is faster than using the Math.Pow method? Like:

```
n * n * n
```

vs

```
Math.Pow ( n, 3 )
```

Comment: The way to achieve performance is (1) set meaningful goals, (2) measure to see if you've met your goals, (3) find the slowest thing if you haven't, (4) optimize the _slowest_ thing until your goal is met. If you have to ask us which is faster then you haven't done steps (2) or (3), and so it is premature to do step (4).

Comment: +Eric Lippert that's true, but it can also be interesting to find out if languages do some magical optimization :P

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Basically, you should **benchmark** to see.

#### Educated Guesswork (unreliable):

*In case it's not optimized to the same thing by some compiler...*

It's very likely that `x * x * x` is faster than `Math.Pow(x, 3)` as `Math.Pow` has to deal with the problem in its general case, dealing with fractional powers and other issues, while `x * x * x` would just take a couple multiply instructions, so it's very likely to be faster.

Comment: why do you believe this to be very likely?

Comment: It takes two integer multiply instructions. In case Math.Pow is not optimized out to the same thing, it probably does much more work (remember, it has to solve a much more general problem, such as fractional powers...)

Comment: "It's very likely that x * x * x is faster than Math.Pow (completely guesswork)."

Something seems off in this sentence.

Comment: You can always open up System.Math in reflector and check it out.  My personal guess is that there's more overhead (possibly negligible granted)to allow it to be a general purpose function, rather than a discrete mathematical calculation.

Comment: I think System.Math is implemented as InternalCall. I haven't checked it though.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Thanks for the additional explanation - I have no disagreement.

Comment: @divo: Indeed, it wasn't really guesswork. It was previous tests that resulted this. I wanted to point out that it really depends on the particular infrastructure that's running your code and you should always rely on benchmarking rather than guessing.

Comment: is that also valid for java and scala?

Comment: I benchmarked this with `Pow(x, 2)` and `Pow(x, 3)`. Multiplication was always more than 100x faster (optimized in Debug and Release). One can safely prefer simple multiplication over Pow functions.

Comment: This does not really seem like an answer to me.

Answer (score 50):

I just reinstalled windows so visual studio is not installed and the code is ugly

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public static class test{

public static void Main(string[] args){
    MyTest();
    PowTest();
}

static void PowTest(){
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    double res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 333333333; i++){
        res = Math.Pow(i,30); //pow(i,30)
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Math.Pow: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms:  " + res);
}

static void MyTest(){
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    double res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 333333333; i++){
        res = MyPow(i,30);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("MyPow: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms:  " + res);
}



static double MyPow(double num, int exp)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    while (exp > 0)
    {
        if (exp % 2 == 1)
            result *= num;
        exp >>= 1;
        num *= num;
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

The results:
csc /o test.cs

test.exe

```
MyPow: 6224 ms:  4.8569351667866E+255  
Math.Pow: 43350 ms:  4.8569351667866E+255
```

Exponentiation by squaring (see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int) is much faster than Math.Pow in my test (my CPU is a Pentium T3200 at 2 Ghz)

EDIT: .NET version is 3.5 SP1, OS is Vista SP1 and power plan is high performance.

Comment: Thanks. Your method seems very good. Is it even better than n*n*n?

Comment: It requires two multiplications, just like n*n*n, but with some overhead, so it will be slightly worse... For an exponent of four (or higher) it may be better than n*n*n*n though, as it still requires only two multiplications, while the direct approach needs three.

Comment: MyPow() works just only for positive numbers. It should starts with             
`if (exp< 0)
                return (1 / MyPow(num, Math.Abs(exp)));`

Comment: You can eek a ~1.5% performance increase by changing modulus to bitwise  check i.e. (exp % 2 == 1) -> ((exp & 1) != 0)

Comment: I just ran this on my laptop but as a .NET Core 2.1 console app and I get the results: MyPow: 23545 ms, Math.Pow: 21109 ms. So obviously MS has improved the performance a lot since this was posted.

Answer (score 16):

A few rules of thumb from 10+ years of optimization in image processing & scientific computing:

Optimizations at an algorithmic level beat any amount of optimization at a low level. Despite the  "Write the obvious, then optimize" conventional wisdom this must be done at the start. Not after.

Hand coded math operations (especially SIMD SSE+ types) will generally outperform the fully error checked, generalized inbuilt ones.

Any operation where the compiler knows beforehand what needs to be done are optimized by the compiler. These include:
1. Memory operations such as Array.Copy()
2. For loops over arrays where the array length is given. As in for (`..; i<array.Length;..`)

Always set unrealistic goals (if you want to).

Answer (score 10):

I just happened to have tested this yesterday, then saw your question now.

On my machine, a Core 2 Duo running 1 test thread, it is faster to use multiply up to a factor of 9. At 10, Math.Pow(b, e) is faster.

However, even at a factor of 2, the results are often not identical. There are rounding errors.

Some algorithms are highly sensitive to rounding errors. I had to literally run over a million random tests until I discovered this.

Comment: Thanks so which one is better to use to minimize rounding errors?

Comment: The Power formula is best for accuracy. However, it depends on the input. For a vast range of numbers, the results are identical. I suggest you test them for your case usage.

Comment: If you used `y = x * x; z = x * y * y; return z * z`  for a total of 4 multiplications, to calculation x^10, it would probably be faster that Math.Pow() again. As for accuracy, Math.Pow() will likely be somewhat more accurate, but only slightly. Math.Pow(b,e) is calculated by `exp(e * log(b))` (probably with some optimization).

Answer (score 5):

This is so micro that you should probably benchmark it for specific platforms, I don't think the results for a Pentium Pro will be necessarily the same as for an ARM or Pentium II.

All in all, it's most likely to be totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

I checked, and `Math.Pow()` is defined to take two doubles.  This means that it can't do repeated multiplications, but has to use a more general approach.  If there were a `Math.Pow(double, int)`, it could probably be more efficient.

That being said, the performance difference is almost certainly absolutely trivial, and so you should use whichever is clearer.  Micro-optimizations like this are almost always pointless, can be introduced at virtually any time, and should be left for the end of the development process.  At that point, you can check if the software is too slow, where the hot spots are, and spend your micro-optimization effort where it will actually make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use the convention x^n. Let's assume n is always an integer.

For small values of n, boring multiplication will be faster, because Math.Pow (likely, implementation dependent) uses fancy algorithms to allow for n to be non-integral and/or negative.

For large values of n, Math.Pow will likely be faster, but if your library isn't very smart it will use the same algorithm, which is not ideal if you know that n is always an integer. For that you could code up an implementation of [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) or some other fancy algorithm.

Of course modern computers are very fast and you should probably stick to the simplest, easiest to read, least likely to be buggy method until you benchmark your program and are sure that you will get a significant speedup by using a different algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.Pow(x, y)` is typically calculated internally as `Math.Exp(Math.Log(x) * y)`. Evey power equation requires finding a natural log, a multiplication, and raising `e` to a power.

As I mentioned in my previous answer, only at a power of 10 does `Math.Pow()` become faster, but accuracy will be compromised if using a series of multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that handbuilt functions are always faster. The cosine functions are way faster and more accurate than anything i could write. As for pow(). I did a quick test to see how slow Math.pow() was in javascript, because Mehrdad cautioned against guesswork

```
    for (i3 = 0; i3 < 50000; ++i3) { 
      for(n=0; n < 9000;n++){ 
        x=x*Math.cos(i3);
      }
    }
```

here are the results:

```
Each function run 50000 times 

time for 50000 Math.cos(i) calls = 8 ms 
time for 50000 Math.pow(Math.cos(i),9000) calls = 21 ms 
time for 50000 Math.pow(Math.cos(i),9000000) calls = 16 ms 
time for 50000 homemade for loop calls 1065 ms
```

if you don't agree try the program at http://www.m0ose.com/javascripts/speedtests/powSpeedTest.html

Comment: This is not very informative. in your custom version you call Math.cos multiple times, while for Mathe.pow it is called once as parameter.

So for a real test replace x = x * math... with x = x * c;
and insert between the two for a c = Math.cos...