# How do I calculate power-of in C#?

Tags: c#, math

I'm not that great with maths and C# doesn't seem to provide a power-of function
so I was wondering if anyone knows how I would run a calculation like this:

```
var dimensions = ((100*100) / (100.00^3.00));
```

Comment: So `var dimensions = 1.0f/100`? :)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

See [Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx). The function takes a value and raises it to a specified power:

```
Math.Pow(100.00, 3.00); // 100.00 ^ 3.00
```

Comment: thanks this was the final calculation:
var dimensions = (100*100)/(Math.Pow(100.00, 3.00));

Answer (score 15):

You are looking for the static method [`Math.Pow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx).

Answer (score 12):

I'm answering this question because I don't find any answer why the `^` don't work for powers. The [`^` operator in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-) is an [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator shorten as *XOR*. The [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) of `A ^ B` shows that it outputs true whenever the inputs differ:

| Input A | Input B | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

Witch means that `100 ^ 3` does this calculation under the hood:

```
decimal   binary
    100 = 0110 0100 
      3 = 0000 0011
    ---   --------- ^
    103 = 0110 0111
```

With is of course not the same as [`Math.Pow(100, 3)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) with results to one million. You can use that or one of the other existing answers.

---

You could also shorten your code to this that gives the same result because C# respects the [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

```csharp
double dimensions = 100 * 100 / Math.Pow(100, 3); // == 0.01
```

Answer (score 6):

The function you want is `Math.Pow` in `System.Math`.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use `Math.Pow`

When i use

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10e7; i++)
{
    var x3 = x * x * x;
    var y3 = y * y * y;
}
```

It only takes 230 ms whereas the following takes incredible 7050 ms:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10e7; i++)
{
    var x3 = Math.Pow(x, 3);
    var y3 = Math.Pow(x, 3);
}
```

Comment: Good, we all expected Math.Pow to be slower. But not that much. Why?  Now let's make homework and check what's the **compiler generated code** (both cs and assembly after JIT) and you might be surprised. Try...

Comment: I was going to rework this one https://github.com/THEjoezack/ColorMine/tree/master/ColorMine/ColorSpaces because there is something like `x*x*x` where I though I could use `x^3`, what I couldnt, so I tried `Math.Pow`

In the Reference Source of math.cs I found this one
`public static extern double Pow(double x, double y);`
So I was not able to look into the code, what did I wrong?

Comment: What should I find out there?

Comment: Your version is faster because your version only uses integers, how would you do `x^x` for example?

Comment: @zedling are you sure that is the reason? I just tried it where x is a double with many decimal places and got the same results! (231ms vs 4870ms): https://dotnetfiddle.net/jgNDfm

Comment: Nope, and after some searching I've found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/936548/4308297

Answer (score 3):

Following is the code calculating power of decimal value for RaiseToPower for both -ve and +ve values.

```
public decimal Power(decimal number, decimal raiseToPower)
        {
            decimal result = 0;
            if (raiseToPower < 0)
            {
                raiseToPower *= -1;
                result = 1 / number;
                for (int i = 1; i < raiseToPower; i++)
                {
                    result /= number;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = number;
                for (int i = 0; i <= raiseToPower; i++)
                {
                    result *= number;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

For powers of 2:

```
var twoToThePowerOf = 1 << yourExponent;
// eg: 1 << 12 == 4096
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Pow()` returns `double` so nice would be to write like this:

```
double d = Math.Pow(100.00, 3.00);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 2;
            int n = -2;
            decimal y = 1;
            if (n > 0)
            {
                for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++)
                    y *= i;               
            }
            if (n < 0)
            {
                for (int x = -1; x >= n; x--)
                    y /= i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(y);
        }
```