# Math.Pow taking an integer value

Tags: c#, floating-accuracy, pow

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx

```
int value = 2;
for (int power = 0; power <= 32; power++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}^{1} = {2:N0}",
                      value, power, (long) Math.Pow(value, power));
```

Math.Pow takes doubles as arguments, yet here we are passing in ints.

Question: Is there any danger of floating point rounding errors if there is an implicit conversion to double happening?

If yes, it is better to use something like:

```
public static int IntPow(int x, uint pow)
{
    int ret = 1;
    while (pow != 0)
    {
        if ((pow & 1) == 1)
            ret *= x;
        x *= x;
        pow >>= 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383587/how-do-you-do-integer-exponentiation-in-c Some good reading in that question and related links

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936541/math-pow-

Comment: And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297454/c-sharp-math-pow-is-not-calculating-correctly) on rounding errors.

Comment: Your first link dash is a good one - thats where I initially got my IntPow code from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an implicit conversion to double happening, and yes there is a possibility of floating point rounding errors as a result.

As to whether it's worth using the alternate method you propose, that's specific to the application.  Is a floating point rounding error entirely unacceptable?  Will you be using numbers that fit within int32 (it doesn't take a whole lot for powers to overflow)?

Comment: floating point rounding error when converting int to double? please write more on that.

Comment: It's not just converting an int to a double, it's converting an int to a double and then doing stuff with it.  As soon as you start performing any operations (add/multiply/whatever) there is at least a possibility of rounding errors.  Since raising to a power is likely to be broken up into a number of add/multiplies, it increases the probability and magnitude of floating point errors.

Comment: you mean as they exist with any IEEE 754 number?

Answer (score 9):

In your special case, when you are calculating 2 to the power x, you can use a simple left shift. This would simplify your code to:

```
public static int TwoPowX(int power)
{
    return (1<<power);
}
```

Comment: And in floating-point, powers of two can be trivially calculated with `ldexp`.  Which .NET doesn't have, but is pretty easy to write using `BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble`.

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no possibility of rounding error caused by the conversion to `double`.  `double` can exactly represent all integers which fall in the domain of the power function.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int IntPow(int number, uint power)
        {
            int result = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < power; i++)
            {
                result *= number;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

for readability!

Comment: There's a reason for the extra code -- this answer is `O(power)`, while the code in the question if `O(log(power))`.