# C# how to do e.g. 5*10^4 or numbers to the power of ten etc

Tags: c#, math

How can I do this in C#?  Is the only way to use Math.Pow?

Comment: 5*10*10*10*10 :) What is wrong with Math.Pow? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-have-a-power-operator.aspx

Comment: Do you need a literal like that, or do you need to perform exponentiation using variables? The former can be done quite simply: 5*(10^4) can be written in C# as `5E4`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639/convert-from-scientific-notation-string-to-float-in-c-sharp

Comment: @dlev The `^` symbol in C# is a bitwise XOR, not a power operator. So instead of `5*(10^4)` being 5000 as you suggest, it is actually 70.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write the literal float constant `5.0e4` (and it works in C, C++, Java, Fortran also).

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own method that does it for you if you don't wish to use Math.Pow.

[C# Efficient Algorithm Integer Based Power Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065249/c-sharp-efficient-algorithm-integer-based-power-function)