# Calculating powers (e.g. 2^11) quickly

Tags: algorithm, exponent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)

How can I calculate powers with better runtime?

E.g. 2^13.

I remember seeing somewhere that it has something to do with the following calculation:

2^13 = 2^8 * 2^4 * 2^1

But I can't see how calculating each component of the right side of the equation and then multiplying them would help me.

Any ideas?

Edit: I did mean with any base. How do the algorithms you've mentioned below, in particular the "Exponentation by squaring", improve the runtime / complexity?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int

Comment: "Exponentation by squaring" calculates `base^exp` in `log(exp)` steps, where *log* is the logarithm with base 2.

Comment: @Nick D, I know I state that in my answer, but I've realized I'm slightly wrong.  It's basically correct if you're using standard integers.  But once you get to using bignums it becomes basically `O(log(n)^2)` because the multiplies take more than O(1) time.

Comment: @Omnifarious, I said log(exp) steps, I didn't specify the *O*.  I agree with you that if we take account of the "multiplication" operation the actual runtime complexity may not be O(logn).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a generalized algorithm for this, but in languages that have bit-shifting, there's a much faster way to compute powers of 2.  You just put in `1 << exp` (assuming your bit shift operator is `<<` as it is in most languages that support the operation).

I assume you're looking for the generalized algorithm and just chose an unfortunate base as an example.  I will give this algorithm in Python.

```
def intpow(base, exp):
   if exp == 0:
      return 1
   elif exp == 1:
      return base
   elif (exp & 1) != 0:
       return base * intpow(base * base, exp // 2)
   else:
       return intpow(base * base, exp // 2)
```

This basically causes exponents to be able to be calculated in log2 exp time.  It's a divide and conquer algorithm.  :-)  As someone else said [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

If you plug your example into this, you can see how it works and is related to the equation you give:

```
intpow(2, 13)
2 * intpow(4, 6)
2 * intpow(16, 3)
2 * 16 * intpow(256, 1)
2 * 16 * 256 == 2^1 * 2^4 * 2^8
```

Answer (score 10):

Use bitwise shifting. Ex. 1 << 11 returns 2^11.

Comment: 2 was used as an example base only. Question is more generic.

Answer (score 3):

Powers of two are the easy ones.  In binary 2^13 is a one followed by 13 zeros.

You'd use bit shifting, which is a built in operator in many languages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). This is also known as "square-and-multiply" and works for bases != 2, too.

Comment: It's really easy to link to wikipedia, and I think links to wikipedia make great supplements to answers, but a link to wikipedia is not an answer except when the answer is really too huge to write down here.

Comment: Why invent the wheel twice? Often, the only crucial thing is to get the right keyword to name a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not limiting yourself to powers of two, then:

k^2n = (k^n)^2

Answer (score 1):

The fastest free algorithm I know of is by [`Phillip S. Pang, Ph.D`](http://www.imach.uran.ru/exp/index.html) and can the source code can be found [here](http://www.imach.uran.ru/exp/exp.zip).
It uses table-driven decomposition, by which it is possible to make exp() function, which is 2-10 times faster, then native exp() of Pentium(R) processor.