# how to calculate 2^32 without multiplying numbers directly?

Tags: algorithm

the simplest way to calculate 2^32 is `2*2*2*2*2......= 4294967296`
, I want to know that is there any other way to get 4294967296? (`2^16 * 2^16` is treated as the same method as `2*2*2....` )

and How many ways to calculate it?
Is there any function to calculate it?

I can't come up with any methods to calculate it without `2*2*2...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating powers (e.g. 2^11) quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198138/calculating-powers-e-g-211-quickly)

Comment: Why are you calculating at all? Here's a function that calculates 4294967296: `f() = 4294967296`.

Comment: Without Fancy(tm) computer operations, doubling a number is as simple as adding it to itself. So, doubling '1' 32 times -- 1 + 1 is 2, 2 + 2 is 4, etc -- suffices.

Comment: On a system where `int` is 32 bits: `-1U + 1ULL`.

Answer (score 9):

```
2 << 31
```

is a bit shift.  It effectively raises 2 to the 32nd power.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but so what it uses two? Shifting one by 32 isn't any less correct.

Comment: Meh.  The operand being raised by a power is 2, not 1.

Comment: I did downvote it, but for a second I was 100% sure that there was `2 << 32`. Nevermind it though

Comment: @pivovarit It was. SO does not show edits that occurred in the first instants.

Comment: I like to think of `x << y` as `x * 2^y`.

Comment: @harold The only use case I can think of is in C, where left-shifting an int by 31 is well-defined, while left-shifting by 32 is not. That being said, I could have misremembered, plus that use case is pointless here since 2^32 overflows.

Comment: @DennisMeng right so it had better be an int64_t or some such and then shifting by 32 would be fine

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a common computer you can left bitshift `2` by `31` (i.e. `2<<31`) to obtain 2^32.

In standard C:

```c
unsigned long long x = 2ULL << 31;
```

---

`unsigned long long` is needed since a simple `unsigned long` is not guaranteed to be large enough to store the value of `2<<31`.

In section **5.2.4.2.1** paragraph 1 of the C99 standard:

> ... the
>   following shall be replaced by expressions that have the same type as would an
>   expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer
>   promotions. Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> — maximum value for an object of type `unsigned long int`
>
> **`ULONG_MAX 4294967295 //`** `2^32 - 1`
>
> — maximum value for an object of type `unsigned long long int`
>
> **`ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615 //`** `2^64 - 1`

Comment: In what you have written, `unsigned long long x = 2<<32;`, if it is C, the shift is on an `int`. This is undefined behavior most everywhere (shifting by more than the width of the type is).

Comment: And it is either 1 << 32 or 2 << 31.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Would an explicit cast as such prevent the UB?

Comment: Yes, `((unsigned long long)2)<<32` is defined. I edited my first comment to include the original code for future readers.

Comment: Instead of the clumsy `(unsigned long long)2` you could also simply write `2ULL`

Comment: @celtschk Wow, I feel silly now for forgetting about literals. :)

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. `1 << 32`
2. `2^32 = (2^32 - 1) + 1 = (((2^32 - 1) + 1) - 1) + 1 = ...`
3. Arrange 32 items on a table. Count the ways you can choose subsets of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not much of a fan of binary magic, then I would suggest **quickpower**.This function computes x<sup>n</sup> in `O(logn)` time.

```
 int qpower(int x,int n)
 {
   if(n==0)return 1;
   if(n==1)return x;
   int mid=qpower(x,n/2);
   if(n%2==0)return mid*mid;
   return x*mid*mid;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `Math.Pow()` (in .NET). I think most language (or environment) would support the similar function for you:

```
Math.Pow(2,32);
```

Comment: The OP didn't specify a programming platform.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess most languages would support the similar function `Pow()`, he asked this `Is there any function to calculate it?` So I think it's a choice. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy/Java you can do something like following with long number (signed integer can be max 2^31 in Java)

```
long twoPOW32 = 1L << 32;
```