# Java: Base to Power of 'N' Problem in Java

Tags: java

**Problem Statement:**

Given base and n that are both 1 or more, compute the value of base to the n power, so `powerN(3, 2)` is 9 (3 squared).

**Example**

```
powerN(3, 1) → 3
powerN(3, 2) → 9
powerN(3, 3) → 27
```

The function signature is `public int powerN(int base, int n)`

I'm finding it to difficult to solve this? Help me out.
**EDIT:** I need a solution which does not uses built in mathematical formulas and recursion

Comment: If it's homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: Have you tried `Math.pow(base, n)`? For homework, you have to solve a problem a given way, in the real world, you usually just want the simplest/best.  This is why you should tag [homework] as such.

Comment: i should not use built in expressions,No its not homework...

Comment: `i should not use built in expressions` why?

Comment: if you should not use this or that, who gave you this task? it really sounds like homework ;)

Comment: Thats what the interviewer told me

Comment: @Deepak, I wonder, why you shouldn't?

Comment: What are you finding difficult?   Do you know how to work out the power of something on paper? If so, do you know how to do this in java?  It doesn't get much simpler.  I understand that a lot of people have bought "java for dummies"; perhaps you'd find it useful?

Comment: For homework, this is useually solved using either a loop or recursion. Which one are you trying, can you post the code you have and the situtation you believe is not working?

Comment: For recursion, you can do this in one to four lines of code, for a loop, you might use two to five. Perhaps the problem is you imagine its much harder than it should be, try to simplify your solution. I can only guess what it is you are trying as you haven't posted it.

Comment: Sorry, but you have to answers, but both are not ok, because you add the additional requirement that no built in and no recursion. So if you have such restrictions, post it in the first place.

Comment: See the EDIT of original question

Comment: @Roflcoptr, I am not sure the OP mentioned recusion. ;)

Comment: Is it just me or does this sound as a thoroughly counterproductive question to ask at an interview?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey He mentioned it in a comment to an answer.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, I wasn't keeping up with the edits, thanks. ;)

Comment: @biziclop, counter productive in the sense that you shouldn't be doing this yourself in any real environment, but useful for the interviewer as its simple to explain and write the answer in a short period of time.

Comment: If I was the interview I would just ask for all three possible approaches. (And any others you can think of, two others come to mind ;)

Comment: Its the bit like the how-would-you-implement-linked-list question. They don't like it when I say, you wouldn't, you would use the built in one unless there is a very good reason not to. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey That's what I meant: asking for as many implementations as you can think of is a good question, setting up arbitrary constraints to get the exact answer you had in mind isn't.

Comment: @biziclop, If I asked this I would expect them to know this is a bad to implement and what might go wrong. e.g. edge cases, performance, maintainability issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public int powerN(int base, int n) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result *= base;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: See also BigInteger. Above code will give unwanted output if it will go beyond int boundary

Answer (score 3):

The most popular method of doing this is like this:

```
sum = base
while (power > 1)
    if (power is even)
        sum = sum * sum
        power = power / 2
    else
        sum = sum * base
        power = power - 1
return sum
```

You can convert to Java, I just wanted to give you the general idea.

Comment: for even better performance I'd use `power >>= 1` instead of `power = power / 2` :)

Comment: @Thomas It's pseudocode. When translating into another language, use whatever works best. Besides, the optimizer should be able to figure that out :-P

Comment: @Thomas: i have done bit shifiting , thats the fastest way.

Comment: Especially in pseudocode! :D :D :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion:

```
public int powerN(int base, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
       return 1;
    } else {
       return (powerN(base, n-1) * base);
    }
}
```

Comment: without recursion...not even recursion

Comment: @Deepak: Then that should have been stated in your question.

Comment: Sorry edited the original question

Comment: +1 for the only recursion answer.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your power stays under int limit

```
int out = 1;
for(int i=n; i>0; i--)
   out = out*base;
return out;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int powerN(int base, int n) {
   return Double.intValue(Math.pow ( base, n));
}
```

Ok I saw you can't use built in functions:

```
public int powerN(int base, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result = result * base;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: **`i should not use built in expressions: OP`**

Comment: Yes I saw it.... in the comments

Answer (score 0):

*Fast way [the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int) from Elias Yarrkov*

***Exponentiation by squaring.***

```
 public static long powerN(long base, long n)
 {
   long result = 1;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        if ((n & 1) == 1)
            result *= base;
        n >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }

    return result;
 }
```