# What is the fastest algorithm to find the power of positive integers?

Tags: algorithm, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)

The only two methods that I know is,

1. A single for loop: extremely slow
2. Rewrite [image] recursively calculate.

I wonder is there a faster algorithm than these two? Any bitwise technique are welcome. Thank you.

C# demos for the two algorithms:

```
     class Math {
        static public Int64 recurPow( Int64 a, Int64 e ) {
            if ( e == 0 )
                return 1;
            if ( e == 1 )
                return a;
            if ( ( e % 2 ) == 0 )
                return recurPow( a * a, e / 2 );
            else
                return recurPow( a * a, ( e - 1 ) / 2 );
        }

        static public Int64 iterPow( Int64 a, Int64 e ) {
            Int64 result = a;
            for ( Int64 i = 1; i < e; ++i )
                result *= a;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @John Zwinck: Thanks a lot. I searched 3 times but couldn't find that thread.

Comment: The fastest algorithm is almost always a pre-computed table lookup :-)

Comment: I believe second recursive call should be like this `recurPow( a * a, ( e - 1 ) / 2 ) * a`. Test it on a = 2, e = 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimal algorithm is NP-complete, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation

That page also links to a number of heuristic algorithms that give pretty good answers, you probably want one of them.

Are you doing comp3212 as well?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not in that class, just get to know it when reading a math book.

Comment: Well we had that problem assigned to us. The lecturer has a habit of "accidentally" assigning unsolvable problems.