# pointer to a function or a functor? function generator

Tags: c++, class, function, expression, functor

I'm trying to build a polynomial function generator, so that it takes a vector (arbitrary size) as argument, and generates a polynomial function I can use later.

for instance,

```
poly_gen(vector<int> power_index)
```

returns a function (or by other method) in forms of (that i can call with another function)

```
y(k)=a0+ a1*n+ a2*n^2 + a3*n^3 + ... + ak*n^k
```

where a0,a1....ak are stored in the vector- power_index

and later I can call it with

```
int calc_poly(int n)
```

and this `calc_poly` can return me a number, calculated by using the polynomial expression generated by `poly_gen()`

PS:
I don't know how to search this question by key words. 
function,construction, generator, pointer, functor...
didn't give me the desired results.

thank you all!

Comment: This relation question could be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't generate functions at runtime in C++, so you're going to have to go with a functor.

You can create an object that stores the coefficients given by `power_index` in some manner (perhaps a direct copy), and give it an `operator() (int n)` operator that will take the coefficients and calculate the value of the polynomial (Horner's rule?).  Then you can pass that object around freely.

So, you need a constructor, an internal representation of the coefficients, and an `operator()` that does the actual calculation.  Should be simple enough.

Comment: well technically you could generate assembly code during runtime and jump to that code

Comment: @Doug T:  Maybe.  There have been systems (probably still are) that don't allow execution of process-writable memory (don't know how they would handle a Lisp compiler or JIT compilers).  In any case, it would be very system-specific.

Answer (score 1):

There was a nice "rosetta stone" [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644246/how-do-you-create-a-function-that-returns-a-function-in-your-language-of-choice) on (almost) this very problem a while back.

There are several C++ answers there: one using [boost::lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644246/how-do-you-create-a-function-that-returns-a-function-in-your-language-of-choice/644636#644636), one using a more [conventional approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644246/how-do-you-create-a-function-that-returns-a-function-in-your-language-of-choice/644305#644305), and one using [MPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644246/how-do-you-create-a-function-that-returns-a-function-in-your-language-of-choice/648373#648373) (and also a [C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644246/how-do-you-create-a-function-that-returns-a-function-in-your-language-of-choice/644768#644768) version, which IMHO would be the ideal solution if your compiler supports it).  Obviously the simple quadratic there will need generalizing to arbitrary numbers of powers but that's simple enough compared with getting your head around the function object concept.

Comment: You can copy the address of the "link"-link under the answer to get an URL with an anchor to it ;)

Comment: Oh! Somehow I never noticed that before!  Thanks, very useful; direct links added above.