# Compute x to x power in the most optimal way possible

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm, logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)

I know this question is pretty easy but my requirement is that I want to compute x to power x where x is a very large number in the best optimize way possible. I am not a math geek and therefore need some help to figure out the best way possible.

In java, we can use BigInteger but how to optimize the code? Any specific approach for the optimization?

Also using recursion will the large value of x, makes the code slow and prone to stack overflow error?

Eg:  457474575 raise to power 457474575

Comment: @learner, bestest? ... seriously?

Comment: You can calculate all the powers of two up to x and multiply all the powers of two which add up to x. Even if you use recursion you wouldn't get more than log2(log2(x)) levels of recursion.

Comment: How do you intend to represent the answer?  The calculation you give will have literally billions of digits.  Do you need all of them?

Comment: @mre, Better than the best. ;)

Comment: @learner, There will be 3,961,897,695 digits which you cannot have in a String.

Comment: Is x always an integer, or can it be a floating point number too? Do you need full precision on the answer, or only the order of magnitude?

Comment: He asks for x^x not x^n - there is possibly a more efficient algorithm for that case.

Answer (score 12):

You do realize that the answer to your example is going to be a very very large number, even for a BigInteger? It will have 3961897696 digits!

The best way to work with really large numbers, if you don't need exact precision, is to work with their logarithms instead. To take x to the x power, take the log of x and multiply it by x. If you need to convert it back take e to the x `exp(x)`, except in this case it will almost certainly overflow.

Comment: +1: You can't have a String in Java that long. ;)

Comment: +1. I wrote basically the same answer (and deleted it again)

Comment: `pow(x,x)` -- giving new meaning to the term *arbitrary precision arithmetic*!

Comment: How do you guys compute the number of digits so precisely?

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux, the log10 representation of an integer, rounded up, is the number of digits. E.g. `log10(1234)` is 3.091, rounded up makes 4.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the simplest optimized approaches:

```
x^1*x^1=x^2
x^2*x^2=x^4
etc...
x^x = x^(x/2)*x^(x/2)*remainder
```

Answer (score 1):

((BigInteger) 457474575).pow(457474575);

Comment: +1: You cannot cast to a BigInteger and you can only do powers up to Integer.MAX_VALUE, but I like your thinking.