# Can calculating Exponentiation, that is, computing x n , can be done in o(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Can calculating Exponentiation, that is, computing x^n , can be done in o(n) time?If so, how would I show this?

Comment: x^n is x * x * x * ... * x. Each increment of `n` causes a **single** additional operation => O(n) operations needed to calculate x^n.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am looking for an algorithm that calculates the power of a number. (x^y), x and y are integers . It must be of complexity O(log\[n\]))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988083/i-am-looking-for-an-algorithm-that-calculates-the-power-of-a-number-xy-x-an)

Comment: @WaiHaLee If you do it by repeated multiplication by x then it's Theta(n), but it can be done in O(log(n)) multiplications.

Comment: @Anonymous - a good point. I was trying to answer the original question (can x^n be calculated in O(n) time?) => it can, but should have mentioned exponentiation by squaring, like amit does in the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30234956/1364007).

Comment: @WaiHaLee I explained it can be done in `o(n)` multiplications, but CANNOT be done in `o(n)` time.

Comment: @amit - whoops, you are quite right. In my haste to reply I wrote "time" when I meant "multiplications".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

On one hand, using [exponent by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), which uses the fact that `x^n = (x^(n/2))^2`, so by repeatidly squaring the number, you can effectively cut down number of multiplications to `O(logN)`. So, if we assume bounded integer size- it is possible to do it in `o(N)`.

**However**, since `k^n`  requires `log_2(k^n) = n*log_2(k)` bits to represent - you cannot do it in `o(n)`, assuming unbounded integers - since the number of bits you need to calculate is itself, `Omega(n)`.