# Calculating powers of integers

Tags: java, math

Is there any other way in Java to calculate a power of an integer?

I use `Math.pow(a, b)` now, but it returns a `double`, and that is usually a lot of work, and looks less clean when you just want to use `int`s (a power will then also always result in an `int`).

Is there something as simple as `a**b` like in Python?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Integers are only 32 bits. This means that its max value is `2^31 -1`. As you see, for very small numbers, you quickly have a result which can't be represented by an integer anymore. That's why `Math.pow` uses `double`.

If you want arbitrary integer precision, use [`BigInteger.pow`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow%28int%29). But it's of course less efficient.

Comment: +1, that's true. But I would consider it nice if the `Java` architects have added `pow(int, int)`. You know sometimes you just want that `5^6` and don't care about doubles at all.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I think they didn't do it because such a method would lead to completely incorrect results in most of the cases. Principle of least astonishment.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. But when you are an ignorant and you work with `int`, nothing stops you to convert to `(int)` an overflowed value.

Comment: I mean if you defined "most of the cases" as "for most value of the inputs" then Java should certainly not offer the `*` operator either for `int` or `long` inputs since for most inputs the multiplication will overflow. In fact, even addition overflows about half the time!

Comment: Sorry if I come in late. Why use double and not long?

Comment: Couldn't `long`s have solved this issue without having to go to floating point?

Comment: The max value of `double` is on the order of 10^308, while the max value for `long` is on the order of 10^19 - huge difference

Answer (score 64):

When it's power of 2. Take in mind, that you can use simple and fast shift expression `1 << exponent`

example:

2<sup>2</sup> = `1 << 2` = `(int) Math.pow(2, 2)`
2<sup>10</sup> = `1 << 10` = `(int) Math.pow(2, 10)`

For larger exponents (over 31) use long instead

2<sup>32</sup> = `1L << 32` = `(long) Math.pow(2, 32)`

btw. in Kotlin you have `shl` instead of `<<` so

(java) `1L << 32` = `1L shl 32` (kotlin)

Answer (score 42):

Best the algorithm is based on the recursive power definition of a^b.

```
long power (long a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)     return 1;
    if (b == 1)     return a;
    if (isEven(b))  return     pow (a * a, b/2);     //even a=(a^2)^b/2
    else            return a * pow (a * a, b/2);     //odd  a=a*(a^2)^b/2

}
```

Running time of  the operation is O(logb).

Sample code with tail-recursive optimization:

```java
public class PowerCalculator {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int base = 7;
        int exponent = 5;
        long result = power(base, exponent);
        System.out.println(base + " ^ " + exponent + " = " + result);
        
    
    }

    public static long power(int a, int b) {
        return powerTailRecursive(a, b, 1);
    }

    private static long powerTailRecursive(int a, int b, long accumulator) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return accumulator;
        } else {
            return powerTailRecursive(a, b - 1, accumulator * a);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:[More information](http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc250/LN250_Weiss/L04-BigOh.htm)

Comment: And what is `isEven(b)` method do? Is it same with `b % 2 == 0`?

Comment: I wonder too ... The guy has gone and left us wondering ... Slipshod programmers ...

Comment: Inexistent `(isEven(b))' function -- meaning `((b & 1) == 0)` -- and an unnecessary complicated algorithm! (

Comment: Better handle case where b<0 to avoid infinite recurssion

Comment: In my benchmarks, this is actually 2x to 20x slower than the [simple loop algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8071402) for the full range of values. The recursion here imposes a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Apostolos "unnecessary complicated algorithm".  Well, no.  It is the standard way to compute (integral) power efficiently.  Optimized algorithms are not "unnecessary complicated algorithm[s]". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int for instance.

Comment: Added  simple code.

Answer (score 38):

No, there is not something as short as `a**b`

Here is a simple loop, if you want to avoid doubles:

```
long result = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
   result *= a;
}
```

If you want to use `pow` and convert the result in to integer, cast the result as follows:

```
int result = (int)Math.pow(a, b);
```

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: given a `long` is 64 bit, then O(n) has 64 as an upper limit. Is that really so bad?

Comment: @Thomas no, you're wrong; if `b` is `2_000_000_000`, then you'll have to do `2e9` operations instead of `31` in [other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20984477/1828937)

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: you'll get a lot of overflow problems in that case. The OP's code does not include argument validation. The maximum number allowed should be 64 in case a is as small as 2 (and for a=1 it doesn't make sense).

Comment: @Thomas overflow issues is not your problem, but problem of runner.

Comment: In my benchmarks, this is actually 2x to 20x faster than the recursive O(log(b)) algorithm for the full range of values. The recursion imposes a lot of overhead.

Comment: An alternative to the loop, but using streams, might look something like:

`long result = LongStream.generate( () -> a ).limit(b).reduce( (i,j) -> i*j ).orElse(1);`

The scope of the OP's question seems to be `b >= 0`, otherwise you need floats/doubles for the result of course.

Comment: The maximum power you can sensibly raise an `int` to is 32, unless you specifically want overflow in order to compute the power modulo 2^32 (which is not likely). Similarly for `long`. Anyone trying to raise a primitive `int` or `long` to the power 2 billion is doing something silly.

Answer (score 9):

Google Guava has math utilities for integers.
[IntMath](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Power {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        int pow = 0;
        int power = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        num = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter power: ");
        pow = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print(power(num,pow));
    }

    public static int power(int a, int b)
    {
        int power = 1;

        for(int c = 0; c < b; c++)
            power *= a;

        return power;
    }

}
```

Comment: Improvement to the `for` loop: `for (; b > 0; b --)`

Comment: serious improvement: square the base and halve the exponent at each step

Answer (score 2):

Guava's math libraries offer two methods that are useful when calculating exact integer powers:

[`pow(int b, int k)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html#checkedPow%28int,%20int%29) calculates b to the kth the power, and wraps on overflow

[`checkedPow(int b, int k)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html#checkedPow%28int,%20int%29) is identical except that it throws `ArithmeticException` on overflow

Personally `checkedPow()` meets most of my needs for integer exponentiation and is cleaner and safter than using the double versions and rounding, etc. In almost all the places I want a power function, overflow is an error (or impossible, but I want to be told if the impossible ever becomes possible).

If you want get a `long` result, you can just use the corresponding [`LongMath`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/math/LongMath.html#checkedPow%28long,%20int%29) methods and pass `int` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can simply use `Math.pow(a,b)` as you have used earlier and just convert its value by using `(int)` before it. Below could be used as an example to it.

```
int x = (int) Math.pow(a,b);
```

where `a` and `b` could be `double` or `int` values as you want.
This will simply convert its output to an integer value as you required.

Comment: I disagree, if `3.0 ^ 1.0 = 2.999999...` due to rounding errors, the answer will be `2` which is wrong.

Comment: @Hidde Yes, you are right friend this certainly has a drawback, thanks for mentioning. It may give wrong result but probably your example here would give the correct result as `3.0`.Just as an example to rounding error for multiplication `2.2*3.0 = 6.0000005` rather than `6.6`.

Comment: @Hidde A Java `double` can represent all Java `ints` exactly. See the Java language specification, section 5.1.2, "[Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)".

Comment: @David, Thanks, however my argument above still holds. The numbers itself will be exact representations but the result of the power may not be. Especially for large powers.

Comment: @Hidde If the result of the power fits in an `int`, it will be exact. If it doesn't fit in an `int`, then decimal expansion is not your problem, overflows are your problem.

Answer (score 2):

A simple (no checks for overflow or for validity of arguments) implementation for the repeated-squaring algorithm for computing the power:

```
/** Compute a**p, assume result fits in a 32-bit signed integer */ 
int pow(int a, int p)
{
    int res = 1;
    int i1 = 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(p); // highest bit index
    for (int i = i1; i >= 0; --i) {
        res *= res;
        if ((p & (1<<i)) > 0)
            res *= a;
    }
    return res;
}
```

The time complexity is logarithmic to exponent p (i.e. linear to the number of bits required to represent p).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to modify(boundaries, even check, negative nums check) Qx__ answer. Use at your own risk. 0^-1, 0^-2 etc.. returns 0.

```
private static int pow(int x, int n) {
        if (n == 0)
            return 1;
        if (n == 1)
            return x;
        if (n < 0) { // always 1^xx = 1 && 2^-1 (=0.5 --> ~ 1 )
            if (x == 1 || (x == 2 && n == -1))
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        if ((n & 1) == 0) { //is even 
            long num = pow(x * x, n / 2);
            if (num > Integer.MAX_VALUE) //check bounds
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
            return (int) num;
        } else {
            long num = x * pow(x * x, n / 2);
            if (num > Integer.MAX_VALUE) //check bounds
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            return (int) num;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

base is the number that you want to power up, n is the power, we return 1 if n is 0, and we return the base if the n is 1, if the conditions are not met, we use the formula **base*(powerN(base,n-1))** eg: 2 raised to to using this formula is : 2(base)*2(powerN(base,n-1)).

```
public int power(int base, int n){
   return n == 0 ? 1 : (n == 1 ? base : base*(power(base,n-1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**There some issues with pow method:**

1. We can replace (y & 1) == 0; with y % 2 == 0
   bitwise operations always are faster.

Your code always decrements y and performs extra multiplication, including the cases when y is even. It's better to put this part into else clause.

```
public static long pow(long x, int y) {
        long result = 1;
        while (y > 0) {
            if ((y & 1) == 0) {
                x *= x;
                y >>>= 1;
            } else {
                result *= x;
                y--;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache has [`ArithmeticUtils.pow(int k, int e)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils.html#pow(int,%20int)).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below logic to calculate the n power of a.

Normally if we want to calculate n power of a. We will multiply 'a' by n number of times.Time complexity of this approach will be O(n)
Split the power n by 2, calculate Exponentattion = multiply 'a' till n/2 only. Double the value. Now the Time Complexity is reduced to O(n/2).

```
public  int calculatePower1(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int val = (b % 2 == 0) ? (b / 2) : (b - 1) / 2;

    int temp = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
        temp *= a;
    }

    if (b % 2 == 0) {
        return temp * temp;
    } else {
        return a * temp * temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way which is built into the language and is short. I do know the algorithm to calculate powers.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {

            try {
                long x = sc.nextLong();
                System.out.println(x + " can be fitted in:");
                if (x >= -128 && x <= 127) {
                    System.out.println("* byte");
                }
                if (x >= -32768 && x <= 32767) {
                    //Complete the code
                    System.out.println("* short");
                    System.out.println("* int");
                    System.out.println("* long");
                } else if (x >= -Math.pow(2, 31) && x <= Math.pow(2, 31) - 1) {
                    System.out.println("* int");
                    System.out.println("* long");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("* long");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(sc.next() + " can't be fitted anywhere.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int arguments are acceptable when there is a double paramter. So Math.pow(a,b) will work for int arguments. It returns double you just need to cast to int.

```
int i =  (int) Math.pow(3,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using pow function and +ve and -ve pow values.

```java
public class PowFunction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;
        int y = -3;
        System.out.println( x + " raised to the power of " + y + " is " + Math.pow(x,y));
        float temp =1;
        if(y>0){
            for(;y>0;y--){
                temp = temp*x;
            }
        } else {
            for(;y<0;y++){
                temp = temp*x;
            }
            temp = 1/temp;
        }
        System.out.println("power value without using pow method.  :: "+temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Unlike Python (where powers can be calculated by a**b) , JAVA has no such shortcut way of accomplishing the result of the power of two numbers.
Java has function named pow in the Math class, which returns a Double value

```
double pow(double base, double exponent)
```

But you can also calculate powers of integer using the same function. In the following program I did the same and finally I am converting the result into an integer (typecasting). Follow the example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*; // CONTAINS THE Math library
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n= sc.nextInt(); // Accept integer n
        int m = sc.nextInt(); // Accept integer m
        int ans = (int) Math.pow(n,m); // Calculates n ^ m
        System.out.println(ans); // prints answers
    }
}
```

Alternatively,
The `java.math.BigInteger.pow(int exponent)` returns a BigInteger whose value is (this^exponent). The exponent is an integer rather than a BigInteger. Example:

```
import java.math.*;
public class BigIntegerDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      BigInteger bi1, bi2; // create 2 BigInteger objects          
      int exponent = 2; // create and assign value to exponent
      // assign value to bi1
      bi1 = new BigInteger("6");
      // perform pow operation on bi1 using exponent
      bi2 = bi1.pow(exponent);
      String str = "Result is " + bi1 + "^" +exponent+ " = " +bi2;
      // print bi2 value
      System.out.println( str );
   }
}
```