# Java: Math.pow returning confusing results

Tags: java

I am looking into Math.pow() function in Java but the following code gives different results as shown below respectively.

Case 1:

```
BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(10,9)+7);
BigDecimal dividend = new BigDecimal(1000000000543543509L);
System.out.println(dividend.remainder(divisor)); // 543543558
```

Case 2:

```
System.out.println((1000000000543543509L%((int)Math.pow(10,9)+7))+""); 
//543543558
```

Case 3:

```
System.out.println((1000000000543543509L%(Math.pow(10,9)+7))+""); //5.43543601E8
```

Why do I get different results in Case 2 and 3 but same in Case 1 and 2?
Which of the above cases is most accurate ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculating powers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071363/calculating-powers-in-java)

Comment: What do you think happens when you do `long a` and `double b`, the calculate `a%b`? Is b treated as a long, or is a treated as a double?

Comment: @nullpointer The problem seems to be the large long that gets cast to double.

Answer (score 1):

In the first two cases, the value of the long retains all of the precision of a long. In the third case, the long is cast to a double, and some of the precision is lost. Note that pow returns a double, and double + int causes the int to be cast to a double. Similarly long%double causes the long to be cast to a double.

We can demonstrate the consequence by performing the cast explicitly:

```
System.out.println((long)((double)1000000000543543509L));
#1000000000543543552
```

You can verify the value is what op gets by using modulo.

```
System.out.println(1000000000543543552L%((int)(Math.pow(10, 9) + 7)));
#543543601
```

So the problem isn't pow, but the long that doesn't fit in a double.

More generally, if we consult the jls on [Widening Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) we can see that long can be promoted to double (or float) without an explicit cast. This is because it doesn't lose any magnitude information. Although, as this example shows, you can lose some precision.