# simplifying nested for loop in C

Tags: c, recursion, for-loop, nested-loops

I am looking for a [narcissistic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) with 3 to 9 digits. I have working code, but the use of nested loops is cumbersome. I think I could use recursion, how?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <time.h>

int power(int a,int b)
{
    int t=1,i;
    for (i=0;i<b;i++)
        t*=a;
    return t;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double t0=clock();
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
    int len=9;
    for (a=1;a<=9;a++)
        for (b=0;b<=9;b++)
            for (c=0;c<=9;c++)
                for (d=0;d<=9;d++)
                    for (e=0;e<=9;e++)
                        for (f=0;f<=9;f++)
                            for (g=0;g<=9;g++)
                                for (h=0;h<=9;h++)
                                    for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
                                {
                                    int num=10*(10*(1000000*a+100000*b+10000*c+1000*d+100*e+10*f+g)+h)+i;
                                    if (num==power(a,len)+power(b,len)+power(c,len)+power(d,len)+power(e,len)+power(f,len)+power(g,len)+power(h,len)+power(i,len))
                                        printf(" %d ",num);
                                }
                                printf("\n耗时： %f s",(clock()-t0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder - how long the program runs?

Comment: I would be surprised if this doesn't suffer from a *lot* of integer overflow, as written. Investigate a bignum library.

Comment: int is more than enough 9*9^9  is the biggest part which fits in int

Comment: @unwind, if he uses `unsigned int` it would fit. `9^9 * 9` is `3,486,784,401`.

Comment: When all indices are 9, it is 9*9^9

Comment: @Sulthan With -O3 just 0.5 secs :)

Comment: @Jack which version VS you use?

Comment: Please, migrate this to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Sulthan Not using VS, just gcc version 4.6.1. Of course I changed _tmain and _TCHAR to main and char

Comment: Here is a recursion version，that is I want
http://www.cnblogs.com/c-hy/archive/2012/09/12/2682642.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `num` is simply iterating through all numbers from `0` (See `Edit 2`) to `999,999,999`. So you really don't need to iterator over every digit. A simple way of doing what you want, even though probably not anymore efficient is this:

```
unsigned int num;
for (num = 0; num < 1000000000; ++num)      // will take long
{
    char digits[15];
    unsigned int i, other_num;
    sprintf(digits, "%09u", i);             // division used here
    other_num = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        other_num += power(digits[j] - '0', len);
    if (num == other_num)
        printf(" %d ",num);
}
```

Note that you can do your `power` function in a more efficient way. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101439/912144).

---

**Edit 1:** (Note: see `Edit 2`)

I am reading through the wikipedia page, and it turns out that you **shouldn't** set `len` to 9, because if you have for example `153`, the `other_num` should be `1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3` (example from Wikipedia).

So you should adjust the loop in the following way:

```
unsigned int num;
for (num = 0; num < 1000000000; ++num)
{
    char digits[15];
    unsigned int i, other_num, len;
    len = snprintf(digits, 10, "%u", i);    // len returned by snprintf
    other_num = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < len; ++j)               // changed 9 to len
        other_num += power(digits[j] - '0', len);
    if (num == other_num)
        printf(" %d ",num);
}
```

---

**Edit 2:**

I just noticed that your number starts from `100,000,000`, so you don't really need to pay attention to `Edit 1`. Nevertheless, I believe it's good to know it in case you needed to change the range of your numbers.

Comment: Exactly what I thought - but also note he uses only 9 different powers so he can efficiently put them into an array.

Comment: Num is starting from 100000000 in the original post, and you don't need to put the number into an array of char to get the digit at position n: you can improve performance using num % 10^(n+1)

Comment: @Jack, you are right, I missed that. I'll edit it. Also, `num % 10^(n+1)` has worse performance than `snprintf`. With `*printf`, there are as many divisions as the number of digits. In your method, there is one division (comes with `%`) and a power per digit.

Comment: @Shahbaz i'm not completely agree. sprintf() is very expensive compared to math operations. It parses the format string, has conditional jumps on length condition, and must copy chars into buffer. Plus, to obtain the decimal representation in somehow it must use a method similar to num%10^n, isn't it? A benchmark would be interesting

Comment: @Shahbaz Ok i tested it :). Using num % pow(10, num+1) is very slow compared to sprintf(). But caching the power of ten (int pow[] = {10, 100, 1000, 10000, ...}) make it go faster than sprintf(). Cheers

Comment: @Jack, just FYI, to get the digits, `*printf` finds a digit by `%10` and then does a `/10` to get the rest of the number. In most CPUs, `/` and `%` can be computed in one instruction. That is why it is fast. Of course, manual conversion is slightly faster (since `*printf` is a more generic function), but I'm not convinced it's _that_ faster. Do you have any figures from your test?

Comment: @Shahbaz Not that faster, just faster: 0.75 of the time. No figures, i already deleted the code. Thanks for clarification about %10 and /10. Fasterer of course

Answer (score 1):

Wonderful loop.
What about this:

```
for( num = 100000000; num <= 999999999; num++ ) {
    int compare = 0;
    for( k = 0; k < 10; k++ ) {
        int position = pow(10, k+1);
        int s = num%position;
        compare += pow(s, 9);
    }
    if( num == compare ) {
        printf("%d\n", num);
    }
}
```

Of course, check for boundaries :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are inspecting all values (`num`) from 1 to `10^len`, if I am not mistaken.
So, a simple `for` cycle from 1 to `10^len` would be enough. Then you can take the digits from `num` and calculate the power value.

I would strongly suggest to calculate the powers 1^len, 2^len ... 9^len first and put them into an array. It will greatly improve performance.