# Converting a string to double value in C

Tags: string

I want to know if parsing a string and converting the numerical string content to double value while writing a code in C will pose any accuracy problems?

If so, what kind of them?

Similarly  are there any problems converting  a double value to string?

If there's a problem, what is the best solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C convert section of char array to double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583965/c-convert-section-of-char-array-to-double)

Answer (score 1):

`atof` will not pose accuracy problems; however, if the string represents an out-of-range double value, it will lead to *undefined behavior* (from [this source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)).

`sprintf` similarly will yield accurate results as long as the buffer you are loading the data into is sufficiently large ([sprintf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)).

Answer (score 0):

Consider also using `strtod` which seems to have better-defined behaviour for erroneous input, particularly in C11.