# Anything wrong with this C++ code

Tags: c++

Can someone please let me know if the following code has something wrong with it ...
In a question I was asked if anything is wrong with the following fibonacci number function.

```
int fib(int n)
{
  if (n <= 1) return n;
  return fib (n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

where n is 0 ... 100

So my answer was nothing as I cannot see anything obvious. The syntax seems fine and logically this is calculating a fibonacci number. Am I correct in making this assumption ?

Comment: Seems fine to me to be honest. Note: just test it??

Comment: Int is probably to narrow for bigger values of fib(), long should be used instead.

Comment: Seriously n = 100? fib(100) == 354'224'848'179'261'915'075, while 2⁶⁴-1 is just 18'446'744'073'709'551'615.

Comment: I dislike the inconsistency of the "space between function name and bracket" in the recursive call back to `fib`... that's certainly a thing that's wrong with the code. Not what you were after?

Comment: I just tested this, the fibonacci numbers themselves where calculated properly, but from n = 20 on or so the whole system got SERIOUSLY slow...

Comment: As KennyTM noticed, in this case, not even unsigned long would suffice. Probably need to use some custom numeric type that can handle such long values... And maybe also rewrite this to tail recursion?

Comment: This could cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depend on what kind of problems you are asking about. I see two problems here:

- Recursion. There is no reason for it. Just use iteration.
- Range overflow. `int` type cant hold all Fibonacci numbers in range [0, 100]

This is an example of fib implementation using iteration in Python(just because it can hold `fib(100)` out of box):

```py
In [16]: def fib(n):
   ....:     curr, next = 0, 1
   ....:     for x in range(n):
   ....:         curr, next = next, curr
   ....:         next += curr
   ....:     return curr
   ....: 

In [17]: fib(100)
Out[17]: 354224848179261915075L
```

Comment: The latter sounds like whats wrong with it. Yeah I compiled the code and ran it but just takes forever to complete. Perhaps use of unsigned long long wouldve done it.

Comment: Not in all cases. The length of `fib(100)` is 21 digits, but `unsigned long long` can hold 19 digits only(if sizeof = 64 bits).

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if the answer is too late, but you should also study the complexity of this function to understand better why it doesn't work fine.

Since for every appeal of the function you call **fib(n-1)** and **fib(n-2)** , the number of operations performed by **fib(n)** will be around **2^n**. Check the following program which counts how many times **fib()** is called:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int cnt = 0;

int fib(int n) {
    cnt++;
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

int main() {
    cout << fib(15) << '\n';
    cout << cnt << '\n';
}
```

So, if you want to call **fib(100)**, it will perform about **10^18** operations, and assuming that your computer is fast enought to make **10^9** operations in **1 second**, it will take like **33 years** to finish this.

But this will cause a stack overflow error earlier.

It is true that **fib(100)** will have more than **19 digits**, which is (aprox.) the max value that **long long** can hold, but this is not the main reason why your function is ***"sticky"***.

A good (and maybe the best) alternative here would be to do as @soon said above, using an **iterative** function / algorithm that have **linear complexity** (your function is **exponential**, read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)).

Here's a code of fibonacci function implemented using big numbers in **C++** (there's more **C** actually, but, anyways):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int maxsize = 10000; // number of digits
int n;

// note that the digits are keep reversed in the vector
// the bigsum function is as you would use add in math
// a = a + b
void bigsum(int a[], int b[]) { // in a[0] I hold the number of digits of 'a'
    int i, t = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= a[0] || i <= b[0] || t; ++i) { // while you still have digits to add
        t = t + a[i] + b[i]; 
        a[i] = t % 10;
        t /= 10;
    }
    a[0] = i - 1; // the new a[0]
}

int zero[maxsize];

// a = b
void copy(int a[], int b[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= b[0]; ++i) {
        a[i] = b[i];
    }
}

void fib(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        cout << "NA";
    } else if (n == 0) {
        cout << 0;
    } else if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        cout << 1;
    } else if (n == 3) {
        cout << 2;
    } else {
        int first[maxsize], second[maxsize], third[maxsize];
        copy(first, zero); copy(second, zero); copy(third, zero);
        first[0] = first[1] = second[0] = second[1] = 1; // initializing the numbers with 1
        third[0] = 1; third[1] = 2; // initializing with 2

        for (int i = 4; i <= n; ++i) {
            copy(first, second);
            copy(second, third); // if you don't understand why these 3, try to do it on a paper
            bigsum(third, first);
        }

        for (int i = third[0]; i >= 1; --i) { // because the digits are reversed
            cout << third[i];
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    cin >> n;
    fib(n);
}
```

Now the **fib** function works for higher numbers (**10000** digits, just change the **maxsize** value if you want higher) and the total number of operations is **n * NUMBER_OF_DIGITS**, which is around **n^2** (way smaller than **2^n**).

Another very nice solution would be using a **2x2 matrix**, which allows you to calculate the remainder **fib(n) % SOME_NUMBER** in aprox. **log2(n)** operations (you can use **"exponentiation by squaring"**, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)). Read more about the matrix solution [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form).

In conclusion, your program isn't good because it runs in **exponential** complexity and also it uses too much stack memory (even if it returns the correct value).

Hope you understand now the issues of your function. Sorry again if this post shouldn't be here.

All the best!