# Why is Math.pow(0, 0) === 1?

Tags: javascript, c++, language-agnostic, pow

We all know that 0<sup>0</sup> is indeterminate.

**But**, *javascript* says that:

```
Math.pow(0, 0) === 1 // true
```

and *C++* says the same thing:

```
pow(0, 0) == 1 // true
```

WHY?

I know that:

```
>Math.pow(0.001, 0.001)
0.9931160484209338
```

But why does `Math.pow(0, 0)` throw no errors? Or maybe a `NaN` would be better than `1`.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Under the standard definition, "a<sup>b</sup> = exp(b ln(a))", it's undefined. Trying to define it as "limit<sub>x->0</sub> f(x)<sup>g(x)</sup>" where "f" and "g" both have limits of zero gives an indeterminate value, since it depends on your choice of functions. (Apologies for the mangled notation; I can't figure out how to get superscripts in comments).

Comment: @MikeSeymour, yes, I'm aware that 0⁰ (use unicode characters) is undefined given that definition, however, if you read my comment you should note that the quotation references the "world of mathematics" rather than any "standard definition". It's this difference that I was originally referring, and the question has been updated to correct this nuance.

Comment: @AJMansfield Um...a^0 = 1 for non-zero a.

Comment: It allows functions that depend upon products of probabilities to deliver sensible results. It's an incorrect notion that computers are symbolic math processors. The C language has a specific implementation in the real world while your mathematical world might be too ideal to be inplemented in silicon.

Comment: For the mathematical version of this question — “why do we often define 0^0 = 1?” — math.stackexchange has lots of good answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1

Comment: IMHO 0^0 *should* be NaN, just as 0/0 is for floating point, because the limit is not uniquely defined. In contrast, 1/0 IS well-defined as Infinity. Anyone who argues that 0^0 should be 1 because x^0=1 for non-zero x is only looking at half of it - don't forget that 0^y=0 for y>0. I think the real answer to this question is "because CS majors are no longer math majors like they were in the 1940's."

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In C++ <strike>[The result of pow(0, 0)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/pow)</strike> the result is basically implementation defined behavior since mathematically we have a contradictory situation where `N^0` should always be `1` but `0^N` should always be `0` for `N > 0`, so you should have no expectations mathematically as to the result of this either. This [Wolfram Alpha](http://community.wolframalpha.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=11131) forum posts goes into a bit more details.

Although having `pow(0,0)` result in `1` is useful for many applications as the  [Rationale for International Standard—Programming Languages—C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) states in the section covering *IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic* support:

> Generally, C99 eschews a NaN result where a numerical value is useful. [...] The results of pow(∞,0) and pow(0,0) are both 1, because there are applications that can exploit this definition. For example, if x(p) and y(p) are any analytic functions that become zero at p = a, then pow(x,y), which equals exp(y*log(x)), approaches 1 as p approaches a.

**Update C++**

As leemes correctly pointed out I originally linked to the reference for the *complex* version of *pow* while the [non-complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) version claims it is *domain error* the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) falls back to the [draft C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and both *C99* and *C11* in section `7.12.7.4` *The pow functions* paragraph *2* says (*emphasis mine*):

> [...]A domain error **may occur** if x is zero and y is zero.[...]

which as far as I can tell means this behavior is [unspecified behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) Winding back a bit section `7.12.1` *Treatment of error conditions* says:

> [...]a domain error occurs if an input argument is outside the domain over
>   which the mathematical function is defined.[...] On a domain error, the function returns an implementation-defined value; if the integer expression math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO is nonzero, the integer expression errno acquires the value EDOM; [...]

So if there was a *domain error* then this would be *implementation defined behavior* but in both the latest versions of `gcc` and `clang` the value of `errno` is `0` so it is not a *domain error* for those compilers.

**Update Javascript**

For *Javascript* the [ECMAScript® Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) in section `15.8` *The Math Object* under `15.8.2.13` *pow (x, y)* says amongst other conditions that:

> If y is +0, the result is 1, even if x is NaN.

Comment: @leemes I believe that page is wrong, the standard does not say that NaN should be returned. The return value is implementation-defined. cplusplus.com which you claim is not a reliable source is actually more accurate here.

Comment: @interjay I guess you mean the deleted answer; I only quoted about its inreliability, hoping it could explain the downvote (which was not by me). Well, both pages are wikis, so their reliability depends on their editors which are human and make mistakes. ;)

Comment: @leemes the C++ community on SO [definitely has a strong dislike for cplusplus.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194788/links-being-changed-to-cppreference-com)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I linked the same question (in the deleted answer).

Comment: @Shafik: Excellent answer; to the point (by citing the authoritative source) but also informative (by citing the rationale).

Comment: @Alek I appreciate the feedback, I try to write the answers I would like to read from others. I don't always succeed but I try. Writing good questions is even harder, I have only attempted that once and I spent way longer on it then I do on my answers.

Answer (score 35):

[In JavaScript `Math.pow` is defined as follows](http://es5.github.io/#x15.8.2.13):

> - If y is NaN, the result is NaN.
> - **If y is +0, the result is 1, even if x is NaN.**
> - If y is −0, the result is 1, even if x is NaN.
> - If x is NaN and y is nonzero, the result is NaN.
> - If abs(x)>1 and y is +∞, the result is +∞.
> - If abs(x)>1 and y is −∞, the result is +0.
> - If abs(x)==1 and y is +∞, the result is NaN.
> - If abs(x)==1 and y is −∞, the result is NaN.
> - If abs(x)<1 and y is +∞, the result is +0.
> - If abs(x)<1 and y is −∞, the result is +∞.
> - If x is +∞ and y>0, the result is +∞.
> - If x is +∞ and y<0, the result is +0.
> - If x is −∞ and y>0 and y is an odd integer, the result is −∞.
> - If x is −∞ and y>0 and y is not an odd integer, the result is +∞.
> - If x is −∞ and y<0 and y is an odd integer, the result is −0.
> - If x is −∞ and y<0 and y is not an odd integer, the result is +0.
> - If x is +0 and y>0, the result is +0.
> - If x is +0 and y<0, the result is +∞.
> - If x is −0 and y>0 and y is an odd integer, the result is −0.
> - If x is −0 and y>0 and y is not an odd integer, the result is +0.
> - If x is −0 and y<0 and y is an odd integer, the result is −∞.
> - If x is −0 and y<0 and y is not an odd integer, the result is +∞.
> - If x<0 and x is finite and y is finite and y is not an integer, the result is NaN.

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

as a general rule, native functions to any language should work as described in the language specification. Sometimes this includes explicitly "undefined behavior" where it's up to the implementer to determine what the result should be, however this is not a case of undefined behavior.

Comment: Annex F in the C99 and C11 standards contains this same specification.  An implementation is supposed to define `__STDC_IEC_559__` to announce that it conforms to this specification.  Annex F describes IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic.  I believe a C specification is allowed to partially conform to Annex F (e.g. pow(0, 0) == 1) and not define `__STDC_IEC_559__`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant hmmm, it seems that in the case of [gcc](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.gcc.help/P4vx6fnqDGg) and [clang](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6981) that piece of information may not be totally helpful, that is discouraging.

Comment: I don't know that this answer helps.  Of course the function should perform as it is defined in the spec.  But then the question just becomes "Why was it defined this way in the spec?"

Comment: Good thing this is (probably) done in hardware, else it would nuke performance with all these special cases :)

Answer (score 17):

It is just convention to define it as `1`, `0` or to leave it `undefined`. The definition [image: pow(0,0)] is wide spread because of the following definition:

[image: mathematical power definition]

---

ECMA-Script documentation says the following about `pow(x,y)`:

> - If y is +0, the result is 1, even if x is NaN.
> - If y is −0, the result is 1, even if x is NaN.

[ http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.13 ]

Comment: math.stackexchange has lots of good discussion and explanations for the definition 0^0=1: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1

Answer (score 14):

According to Wikipedia:

> In most settings not involving continuity in the exponent, interpreting 0<sup>0</sup> as 1 simplifies formulas and eliminates the need for special cases in theorems.

There are several possible ways to treat `0**0` with pros and cons to each (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) for an extended discussion).

The [IEEE 754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) floating point standard recommends three different functions:

- `pow` treats `0**0` as `1`. This is the oldest defined version. If the power is an exact integer the result is the same as for `pown`, otherwise the result is as for `powr` (except for some exceptional cases).
- `pown` treats 0**0 as 1. The power must be an exact integer. The value is defined for negative bases; e.g., `pown(−3,5)` is `−243`.
- `powr` treats 0**0 as NaN (Not-a-Number – undefined). The value is also NaN for cases like `powr(−3,2)` where the base is less than zero. The value is defined by exp(power'×log(base)).

Answer (score 7):

## Donald Knuth

sort of settled this debate in 1992 with the following:

[image]

And went even more into details in his paper [Two Notes on Notation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9205211v1.pdf).

Basically, while we don't have 1 as the limit of `f(x)/g(x)` for all not all functions `f(x)` and `g(x)`, it still makes combinatorics so much simpler to define `0^0=1`, and then just make special cases in the few places where you need to consider functions such as `0^x`, which are weird anyway. After all `x^0` comes up a lot more often.

Some of the best discussions I know of this topic (other than the Knuth paper) are:

- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054856/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.0.to.0.power.html)
- http://www.quora.com/Mathematics/What-is-math-0-0-math?share=1
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475337/the-binomial-formula-and-the-value-of-00

Comment: If you have not read some read the answers in [Zero to the zero power...?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1) which was linked off the question you should some of the answers covers this approach as well.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to know what value you should give to `f(a)` when `f` isn't directly computable in `a`, you compute the limit of `f` when `x` tends towards `a`.

In case of `x^y`, usual limits tend towards `1` when `x` and `y` tend to `0`, and especially `x^x` tends towards `1` when `x` tends to `0`.

See http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10005.3-5.shtml

Answer (score 5):

The C language definition says (7.12.7.4/2):

> A domain error may occur if x is zero and y is zero.

It also says (7.12.1/2):

> On a domain error, the function returns an implementation-defined value; if the integer expression math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO is nonzero, the integer expression errno acquires the value EDOM; if the integer expression math_errhandling & MATH_ERREXCEPT is nonzero, the ‘‘invalid’’ floating-point exception is raised.

By default, the value of `math_errhandling` is `MATH_ERRNO`, so check `errno` for the value `EDOM`.

Comment: Whoups! That's really interesting! I compiled my cpp file using `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) 4.8.`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to disagree with some of the previous answers' assertion that it's a matter of convention or convenience (covering some special cases for various theorems, etc) that 0^0 be defined as 1 instead of 0.

Exponentiation doesn't actually fit that well with our other mathematical notations, so the definition we all learn leaves room for confusion. A slightly different way of approaching it is to say that a^b (or exp(a, b), if you like) returns the value **multiplicatively equivalent** to multiplying **some other thing** by a, repeated b times.

When we multiply 5 by 4, 2 times, we get 80. We've multiplied 5 by 16. So 4^2 = 16.

When you multiply 14 by 0, 0 times, we are left with 14. We've multiplied it 1. Hence, 0^0 = 1.

This line of thinking might also help to clarify negative and fractional exponents. 4^(-2) is a 16th, because 'negative multiplication' is division - we divide by four twice.

a^(1/2) is root(a), because multiplying something by the root of a is half the **multiplicative work** as multiplying it by a itself - you would have to do it twice to multiply something by 4 = 4^1 = (4^(1/2))^2

Comment: This is still conventional. And the convenience reasons for application in the program languages are well-documented in several specifications, so the reason to take alternative definitions is quite weak, despite your disagreement.

Answer (score 0):

For this to understand you need to solve calculus:

[image]

Expanding `x^x` around zero using Taylor series, we get:

[image]

So to understand what's going on with limit when `x` goes to zero,
we need to find out what's going on with second term `x log(x)`, because other terms are proportional to `x log(x)` raised to some power.

We need to use transformation:

[image]

Now after this transformation we can use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), which states that:

[image]

So differentiating that transformation we get:

[image]

So we've calculated that term `log(x)*x` approaches 0 when x approaches 0.
It's easy to see that other consecutive terms also approaches zero and even faster than second term.

So at point `x=0`, series becomes `1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + ...` and thus equals to 1.

Comment: While this answer is impressive, it's worth noting that in math, the 
limit as x->a of f(x) doesn't necessarily equal f(a), unless the function is continuous at x.