# Is memset(&obj, 0, sizeof obj) less portable than initializing with {0}?

Tags: c, memset

I recently ran into GCC's bug that prevents initializing some things with `{0}`. [In that bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53119), the person reporting it says:

> The classic example in the C standard library is mbstate_t:

```
mbstate_t state = { 0 }; /* correctly zero-initialized */
```

> versus the common but nonportable:

```
mbstate_t state;
memset(&state, 0, sizeof state);
```

While I prefer and try to use `{0}` to initialize something to zero, I have used, and have seen others use, the `memset` version to set something to zero. I haven't run into any portability issues in the past.

**Question**: Is using `memset` here really nonportable? If so, in what circumstances would it be nonportable?

Comment: iiuc, that bug doesn't *prevent* initializing struct's with `={0}`; it just presents an unnecessary warning which could be suppressed in all the usual ways. It's a bug, certainly, and it's marked as resolved (and only two years after the report :) )

Comment: @rici: Yeah, you're right. I build with `-Werror` so sometimes I forget what's normally an error and what's normally a warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bitwise zero isn't guaranteed to be `(T)0` for floating-point and pointer types.  So if you `memset` one of those to zero, you're getting something that's at best implementation-defined.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597142/when-was-the-null-macro-not-0) lists a few machines where the null pointer wasn't bitwise zero.

I believe Cray made a few examples of machines where bitwise zero didn't make your floating-point number zero.

Comment: `memset` initialization works for "the types float and double, but only if the implementation has defined the macro __STDC_IEC_559__ to declare that it conforms to the IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic annex"

Comment: I don't really consider examples where `NULL` is not zero to be valid because the standard requires `NULL` to be "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`".

Comment: @Cornstalks: You're misinterpreting the standard.  The standard requires that the integral constant 0, when converted to a pointer type, to yield the null pointer.  It does NOT require that the null pointer be represented by bitwise zero.  See also http://c-faq.com/null/machnon0.html .

Comment: @YePhIcK that macro may not be accurate, see my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955968/why-is-math-pow0-0-1/19955996#comment29710753_19956041).

Answer (score 1):

"The use of memset for this purpose makes the assumption that a bit pattern of all zeros corresponds to a numeric value of zero or a pointer value of null. This is true for most types in most implementations of C, but is not a requirement of the ISO standard".

The above quote is taken from http://www.codepolice.org/c/memset.html (which was the first Google hit for "portability issues with memset")

Answer (score 1):

> Is using `memset` here really nonportable?

It depends.

> If so, in what circumstances would it be nonportable?

Setting an integer to zero bits using `memset` *always* makes the integer zero.
Setting a floating-point number to zero bits using `memset` *usually* makes number zero, but this is not guaranteed-- *it depends on how floating point numbers are stored*.
The story is same for pointers; a pointer whose bits are set to be zero isn't necessary a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Do you know, what the portable way for `mbstate_t` is? C11 p. 7.29.6 (3) „[…] A zero-valued `mbstate_t` object can be used to initiate conversion involving any multibyte character sequence, […]“. I'm not sure, what “zero-valued” means. [This](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=mbsinit&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy) says, `{0}` is the less portable way, but this is actually what I thought “zero-valued” means.