# Efficient 10 power x algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, calculator

Can anyone help me with finding an efficient code to find 10 power x?

```
 private int power(int base, int exp)
{
    int result = 1;
    while (exp != 0)
    {
        if ((exp & 1) == 1)
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Source of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int), but I am looking for a way where the input could be 3.14 (double). I also cannot use any library functions. The power can be a real number. So it is not just a simple integer algorithm where we can find by Exponentiation by Squaring.

Comment: This code has been copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int You should give credit to the oreginal src

Comment: So...why can't you use existing library functions? They exist for a reason - so people can use them...they're also generally well written and efficient.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this without library functions. You could use `pow` or `exp` and `log`

Comment: why don't you wish to use the existing library functions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of calculating `10^x` you can calculate `e^(x*ln(10))`. So your question boil down to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18445/fastest-way-to-calculate-ex-upto-arbitrary-number-of-decimals). I can offer a simple implementation by calculating the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function):

```
double tenPow(double x) {
    // ln(10)
    double logTen = 2.3025850929940456840179914546843642076011014886287729;
    double sum = 0.;
    x *= logTen; // x * ln(10)
    double tmp = 1.;
    for (double i = 1.; tmp > 0.; i += 1.) {
        sum += tmp;
        tmp *= x;
        tmp /= i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**EDIT1**
As noted in the comment this method is not effective for large `x`. But we can break `x` into its integer and fractional parts, so `x = xi + xf`. `e^(xi + xf) = e^xf * e^xi`. `e^xi` can be effectively calculated using recursive exponentiation. And `e^xf` can be calculated using the Taylor series.

**EDIT2**
Here is my implementation of this algorithm:

```
public static double fastTenPow(double x) {
    if (x < 0.) {
        return 1. / fastTenPow(-x);
    }
    int intPart = (int) x;
    double fractPart = x - intPart;
    return fractTenPow(fractPart) * intTenPow(intPart);
}

private static double intTenPow(int x) { // copied it
    double res = 1.;
    double base = 10.;
    while (x != 0) {
        if ((x & 1) == 1) {
            res *= base;
        }
        x >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }
    return res;
}

private static final double LOG_TEN = 2.3025850929940456840179914546843642076011014886287729;
private static final double EPS = 0.00000000000000001;

private static double fractTenPow(double x) {
    double sum = 0.;
    x *= LOG_TEN;
    double tmp = 1.;
    for (double i = 1.; tmp > EPS; i += 1.) {
        sum += tmp;
        tmp *= x;
        tmp /= i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This is not very efficient (nor accurate) if `x` gets larger. Accuracy is also very bad for `x < 0`.

Comment: both exp and log can be computed by binary search algorithms on fixed point variables ... and also they are present on FPU x87 coprocesor directly so on PC there is no need for math lib just use asm ...

Answer (score 7):

Why dont you use [Math.pow(double, double)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29)

you can even check out the source.

---

Comment: I want an algorithm which solves without using any existing library functions. I will update my question.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Java. I searched google but could not find the math.class code. Could you please post the link? There is no code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StrictMath.java#StrictMath.pow%28double%2Cdouble%29\

Comment: slow. it uses fpu and logarithms, even if native, you're looking at hundreds of clock cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `pow` method from a Java `StrictMath` implementation. Technically, `StrictMath` favors accuracy over performance, but in practice it's pretty fast as it's used everywhere in Java I copied and formatted the sources necessary for the `pow` function for you :) :

```
public class YourMathClass {
    public static double pow(double x, double y) {
        // Special cases first.
        if (y == 0)
            return 1;
        if (y == 1)
            return x;
        if (y == -1)
            return 1 / x;
        if (x != x || y != y)
            return Double.NaN;
        // When x < 0, yisint tells if y is not an integer (0), even(1),
        // or odd (2).
        int yisint = 0;
        if (x < 0 && floor(y) == y)
            yisint = (y % 2 == 0) ? 2 : 1;
        double ax = abs(x);
        double ay = abs(y);
        // More special cases, of y.
        if (ay == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
            if (ax == 1)
                return Double.NaN;
            if (ax > 1)
                return y > 0 ? y : 0;
            return y < 0 ? -y : 0;
        }
        if (y == 2)
            return x * x;
        if (y == 0.5)
            return sqrt(x);
        // More special cases, of x.
        if (x == 0 || ax == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY || ax == 1) {
            if (y < 0)
                ax = 1 / ax;
            if (x < 0) {
                if (x == -1 && yisint == 0)
                    ax = Double.NaN;
                else if (yisint == 1)
                    ax = -ax;
            }
            return ax;
        }
        if (x < 0 && yisint == 0)
            return Double.NaN;
        // Now we can start!
        double t;
        double t1;
        double t2;
        double u;
        double v;
        double w;
        if (ay > TWO_31) {
            if (ay > TWO_64) // Automatic over/underflow.
                return ((ax < 1) ? y < 0 : y > 0) ? Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY : 0;
            // Over/underflow if x is not close to one.
            if (ax < 0.9999995231628418)
                return y < 0 ? Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY : 0;
            if (ax >= 1.0000009536743164)
                return y > 0 ? Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY : 0;
            // Now |1-x| is <= 2**-20, sufficient to compute
            // log(x) by x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4.
            t = x - 1;
            w = t * t * (0.5 - t * (1 / 3.0 - t * 0.25));
            u = INV_LN2_H * t;
            v = t * INV_LN2_L - w * INV_LN2;
            t1 = (float) (u + v);
            t2 = v - (t1 - u);
        } else {
            long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(ax);
            int exp = (int) (bits >> 52);
            if (exp == 0) // Subnormal x.
            {
                ax *= TWO_54;
                bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(ax);
                exp = (int) (bits >> 52) - 54;
            }
            exp -= 1023; // Unbias exponent.
            ax = Double.longBitsToDouble((bits & 0x000fffffffffffffL) | 0x3ff0000000000000L);
            boolean k;
            if (ax < SQRT_1_5)  // |x|<sqrt(3/2).
                k = false;
            else if (ax < SQRT_3) // |x|<sqrt(3).
                k = true;
            else {
                k = false;
                ax *= 0.5;
                exp++;
            }
            // Compute s = s_h+s_l = (x-1)/(x+1) or (x-1.5)/(x+1.5).
            u = ax - (k ? 1.5 : 1);
            v = 1 / (ax + (k ? 1.5 : 1));
            double s = u * v;
            double s_h = (float) s;
            double t_h = (float) (ax + (k ? 1.5 : 1));
            double t_l = ax - (t_h - (k ? 1.5 : 1));
            double s_l = v * ((u - s_h * t_h) - s_h * t_l);
            // Compute log(ax).
            double s2 = s * s;
            double r = s_l * (s_h + s) + s2 * s2 * (L1 + s2 * (L2 + s2 * (L3 + s2 * (L4 + s2 * (L5 + s2 * L6)))));
            s2 = s_h * s_h;
            t_h = (float) (3.0 + s2 + r);
            t_l = r - (t_h - 3.0 - s2);
            // u+v = s*(1+...).
            u = s_h * t_h;
            v = s_l * t_h + t_l * s;
            // 2/(3log2)*(s+...).
            double p_h = (float) (u + v);
            double p_l = v - (p_h - u);
            double z_h = CP_H * p_h;
            double z_l = CP_L * p_h + p_l * CP + (k ? DP_L : 0);
            // log2(ax) = (s+..)*2/(3*log2) = exp + dp_h + z_h + z_l.
            t = exp;
            t1 = (float) (z_h + z_l + (k ? DP_H : 0) + t);
            t2 = z_l - (t1 - t - (k ? DP_H : 0) - z_h);
        }
        // Split up y into y1+y2 and compute (y1+y2)*(t1+t2).
        boolean negative = x < 0 && yisint == 1;
        double y1 = (float) y;
        double p_l = (y - y1) * t1 + y * t2;
        double p_h = y1 * t1;
        double z = p_l + p_h;
        if (z >= 1024) // Detect overflow.
        {
            if (z > 1024 || p_l + OVT > z - p_h)
                return negative ? Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY : Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        } else if (z <= -1075) // Detect underflow.
        {
            if (z < -1075 || p_l <= z - p_h)
                return negative ? -0.0 : 0;
        }
        // Compute 2**(p_h+p_l).
        int n = round((float) z);
        p_h -= n;
        t = (float) (p_l + p_h);
        u = t * LN2_H;
        v = (p_l - (t - p_h)) * LN2 + t * LN2_L;
        z = u + v;
        w = v - (z - u);
        t = z * z;
        t1 = z - t * (P1 + t * (P2 + t * (P3 + t * (P4 + t * P5))));
        double r = (z * t1) / (t1 - 2) - (w + z * w);
        z = scale(1 - (r - z), n);
        return negative ? -z : z;
    }

    public static int round(float f) {
        return (int) floor(f + 0.5f);
    }

    public static double floor(double a) {
        double x = abs(a);
        if (!(x < TWO_52) || (long) a == a)
            return a; // No fraction bits; includes NaN and infinity.
        if (x < 1)
            return a >= 0 ? 0 * a : -1; // Worry about signed zero.
        return a < 0 ? (long) a - 1.0 : (long) a; // Cast to long truncates.
    }

    public static double abs(double d) {
        return (d <= 0) ? 0 - d : d;
    }

    public static double sqrt(double x) {
        if (x < 0)
            return Double.NaN;
        if (x == 0 || !(x < Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY))
            return x;
        // Normalize x.
        long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(x);
        int exp = (int) (bits >> 52);
        if (exp == 0) // Subnormal x.
        {
            x *= TWO_54;
            bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(x);
            exp = (int) (bits >> 52) - 54;
        }
        exp -= 1023; // Unbias exponent.
        bits = (bits & 0x000fffffffffffffL) | 0x0010000000000000L;
        if ((exp & 1) == 1) // Odd exp, double x to make it even.
            bits <<= 1;
        exp >>= 1;
        // Generate sqrt(x) bit by bit.
        bits <<= 1;
        long q = 0;
        long s = 0;
        long r = 0x0020000000000000L; // Move r right to left.
        while (r != 0) {
            long t = s + r;
            if (t <= bits) {
                s = t + r;
                bits -= t;
                q += r;
            }
            bits <<= 1;
            r >>= 1;
        }
        // Use floating add to round correctly.
        if (bits != 0)
            q += q & 1;
        return Double.longBitsToDouble((q >> 1) + ((exp + 1022L) << 52));
    }

    private static double scale(double x, int n) {
        //       if (Configuration.DEBUG && abs(n) >= 2048)
        //         throw new InternalError("Assertion failure");
        if (x == 0 || x == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || !(x < Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) || n == 0)
            return x;
        long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(x);
        int exp = (int) (bits >> 52) & 0x7ff;
        if (exp == 0) // Subnormal x.
        {
            x *= TWO_54;
            exp = ((int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(x) >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 54;
        }
        exp += n;
        if (exp > 0x7fe) // Overflow.
            return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY * x;
        if (exp > 0) // Normal.
            return Double.longBitsToDouble((bits & 0x800fffffffffffffL) | ((long) exp << 52));
        if (exp <= -54)
            return 0 * x; // Underflow.
        exp += 54; // Subnormal result.
        x = Double.longBitsToDouble((bits & 0x800fffffffffffffL) | ((long) exp << 52));
        return x * (1 / TWO_54);
    }

    private static final double TWO_31 = 0x80000000L, // Long bits 0x41e0000000000000L.
            TWO_52 = 0x10000000000000L, // Long bits 0x4330000000000000L.
            TWO_54 = 0x40000000000000L, // Long bits 0x4350000000000000L.
            TWO_64 = 1.8446744073709552e19; // Long bits 0x7fe0000000000000L.
    private static final double L1 = 0.5999999999999946, // Long bits 0x3fe3333333333303L.
            L2 = 0.4285714285785502, // Long bits 0x3fdb6db6db6fabffL.
            L3 = 0.33333332981837743, // Long bits 0x3fd55555518f264dL.
            L4 = 0.272728123808534, // Long bits 0x3fd17460a91d4101L.
            L5 = 0.23066074577556175, // Long bits 0x3fcd864a93c9db65L.
            L6 = 0.20697501780033842, // Long bits 0x3fca7e284a454eefL.
            P1 = 0.16666666666666602, // Long bits 0x3fc555555555553eL.
            P2 = -2.7777777777015593e-3, // Long bits 0xbf66c16c16bebd93L.
            P3 = 6.613756321437934e-5, // Long bits 0x3f11566aaf25de2cL.
            P4 = -1.6533902205465252e-6, // Long bits 0xbebbbd41c5d26bf1L.
            P5 = 4.1381367970572385e-8, // Long bits 0x3e66376972bea4d0L.
            DP_H = 0.5849624872207642, // Long bits 0x3fe2b80340000000L.
            DP_L = 1.350039202129749e-8, // Long bits 0x3e4cfdeb43cfd006L.
            OVT = 8.008566259537294e-17; // Long bits 0x3c971547652b82feL.
    private static final double SQRT_1_5 = 1.224744871391589, // Long bits 0x3ff3988e1409212eL.
            SQRT_3 = 1.7320508075688772, // Long bits 0x3ffbb67ae8584caaL.
            CP = 0.9617966939259756, // Long bits 0x3feec709dc3a03fdL.
            CP_H = 0.9617967009544373, // Long bits 0x3feec709e0000000L.
            CP_L = -7.028461650952758e-9, // Long bits 0xbe3e2fe0145b01f5L.
            LN2 = 0.6931471805599453, // Long bits 0x3fe62e42fefa39efL.
            LN2_H = 0.6931471803691238, // Long bits 0x3fe62e42fee00000L.
            LN2_L = 1.9082149292705877e-10, // Long bits 0x3dea39ef35793c76L.
            INV_LN2 = 1.4426950408889634, // Long bits 0x3ff71547652b82feL.
            INV_LN2_H = 1.4426950216293335, // Long bits 0x3ff7154760000000L.
            INV_LN2_L = 1.9259629911266175e-8; // Long bits 0x3e54ae0bf85ddf44L.
}
```

Now, if you're *really* into making things go really fast for large-scale computations (I mean hundreds of thousands of `pow` method calls), may I suggest this extremely fast [`pow`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/FastMath.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) function from the [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/utilities.html) [`FastMath`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/FastMath.html) class?

According to your question, you don't want to have another library, so I copied the necessary parts of the `FastMath` and `FastMathLiteralArrays` in one file for you. It's too big to put on StackOverflow, so I put up on PasteAll:

> http://www.pasteall.org/53238/java

**WARNING:** This file is huge in terms of code. Unless you are sure you are doing extremely long computations using `pow`, you shouldn't use this file because 1) It will use a ton of memory and 2) It may actually go *slower* if you are just going to use it once or twice.

Anyways, hope this answers all you `pow` efficiency needs :) (I also hope I'll get the bounty ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Catering for `double` input without using library code is pointless - you either have to use libraries or plagiarise the source for library code - same thing.

However for integer arithmetic, not using libraries is plausible.

Answering your question as stated and titled:

```
private static int tenToPower(int power) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int p = 0; p < power; p++)
        result *= 10;
    return result;
}
```

Since your return type is `int` in your example code, I have assumed that negative powers, which would produce fractional results, are out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

If you want really fast and efficient power of 10, and only need integers, you can use a table (really old trick from the 90s), like this:

```
static final long powerOfTen[] = {1,10,100,1000,10000, ....} // you get the idea
```

and then

```
static long powerOfTen(long input, int power) {
    return input * powerOfTen[power];
}
```

If you need greater precision, you can also pre-calculate that, but keep in mind as the table gets bigger, you win less and less since it uses more memory/L1 cache. The point above is that because of its really small size the static method would be inlined, and the static array is so small that if fits a 64 byte L1 cache page, meaning that performance-wise, this would come down to an integer multiplication on registers.

Comment: How does this answer `Efficient 10 power x algorithm […] where [x] could be 3.14 (double).`

Answer (score -3):

can't you use a simple recursion?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(power10x(4,1)); //replace ur X value with 4

}


public static int power10x(int a,int val){
     if(a==0)
        return val;
     else
         return power10x(a-1,val*10);

}
```

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24847761/616460), and also the OP specified that `a` should be a `double`.