# Java Math.pow(a,b) time complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity

I would like to ask  time complexity of the following code. Is it O(n)? (Is time complexity of Math.pow()  O(1)? ) In general, is Math.pow(a,b) has time complexity O(b) or O(1)? Thanks in advance.

```
public void foo(int[] ar) {
   int n = ar.length;
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

     sum += Math.pow(10,ar[i]);

   }
}
```

Comment: if you only want integer powers, writing your own power function is better. As there are only a few powers of 10 that fit in an int, simply use a lookup table and you're good with O(1)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc,  but doing iteratively means you do b operations for a^b. isnt it?. In the original question, if the array length is n, then the range of array is between 0 and n, and the max is at least n-1. Thus above code will have complexity O(n^2) isn it?

Comment: Where did I say thay you do iteratively for powers? What I said is a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) like `int pow10[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000,... 1000000000};` and to get `Math.pow(10, i)` simply use `pow10[i]`. Even if you do multiply manually, you only need O(log n) with [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) ([The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/101439/995714)), not O(n) like doing it iteratively

Comment: Oh I see what you meant, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Blindy talks about *possible* approaches that Java could take in implementing `pow`.

First of all, the general case *cannot* be repeated multiplication.  It won't work for the general case where the exponent is not an integer.  (The signature for `pow` is `Math.pow(double, double)`!)

In the OpenJDK 8 codebase, the native code implementation for `pow` can work in two ways:

- The first implementation in `e_pow.c` uses a power series.  The approach is described in the C comments as follows:

  ```
  * Method:  Let x =  2   * (1+f)
  *      1. Compute and return log2(x) in two pieces:
  *              log2(x) = w1 + w2,
  *         where w1 has 53-24 = 29 bit trailing zeros.
  *      2. Perform y*log2(x) = n+y' by simulating multi-precision
  *         arithmetic, where |y'|<=0.5.
  *      3. Return x**y = 2**n*exp(y'*log2)
  ```
- The second implementation in `w_pow.c` is a wrapper for the `pow` function provided by the Standard C library.  The wrapper deals with edge cases.

Now it is possible that the Standard C library uses CPU specific math instructions.  If it did, and the JDK build (or runtime) selected<sup>1</sup> the second implementation, then Java would use those instructions too.

But either way, I can see no trace of any special case code that uses repeated multiplication.  You can safely assume that it is `O(1)`.

---

<sup>1 - I haven't delved into how when the selection is / can be made.</sup>

Comment: It is never necessary to use repeated multiplication. There is an *O(log N)* algorithm for integer exponentiation.

Comment: @EJP - 1) What is "necessary" and what actually happens are not the same thing.  2) For `int` and `long`, you can probably tune the algorithm with special cases so that `O(N)` is faster than `O(logN)` in the range of `N` and `X` where you don't get integer overflow.

Comment: @EJP  E.g. treat X == 0, 1 and 2 and X < 0 as special cases.  If you deal with the X==2 case using shifts, log3(2^32) is < 21; i.e. X >= 3 requires 21 or less rounds of repeated multiplication.

Answer (score 6):

You can consider `Math.pow` to be O(1).

There's a few possible implementations, ranging from a CPU assembler instruction (Java doesn't use this) to a stable software implementation based on (for example) the Taylor series expansion over a few terms (though not exactly the Taylor implementation, there's some more specific algorithms).

It most definitely won't repeatedly multiply if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: Why wouldn't Java use the assembler instruction? The implementation is native.

Comment: Nobody does, including C. The hardware implementation isn't fully standards compliant (in respect to NaN handling IIRC). You have to explicitly force the C compiler to use hardware instructions (`-ffastmath` for gcc for example).

Comment: @chrylis No computer architecture I know has an instruction for calculating powers. The simplest implementation would be `exp(b*log(a))`