# Did I just increase the complexity of reversing a number?

Tags: java, algorithm, reverse

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

    int  orig=103, reverse=0, mod;
    int numOfDigits=0;
    int n = orig;

    while (n>0){
        n /= 10;
        numOfDigits++;
    }
    n = orig;
    while (n > 0){
        mod = n % 10;
        reverse = reverse + (int)(mod * java.lang.Math.pow(10, numOfDigits-1));
        numOfDigits--;
        n /= 10;
    }

System.out.println("Reversed is : " + reverse);
 }
```

}

I do know that `reverse = reverse + (int)(mod * java.lang.Math.pow(10, numOfDigits-1));` can be replaced by `reverse = mod + (reverse*10)`.

Was wondering if I had just increased the complexity of a simple program by calculating total number of digits and applying power?

P.S: Kindly assume that orig can be taken as an input from the user and could be a number of any number of digits. I have hard coded only for experiment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't increase the complexity ... but you did make it slower.  The expression  `pow(10, numOfDigits - 1)` will be substantially slower than `reverse = mod + (reverse * 10)`

<sup>It is also possible that a computation that uses `Math.pow` instead of integer multiplication is inaccurate due to floating point imprecision.  A `double` has only 52 bits of precision, compared with 63 for a `long`.  In this example, this probably doesn't apply, but it is something to be wary of, in general</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Probably, this would be the best approach with **less iteration** & **complexity**:

```
public class NumReverse {

public long reverseNumber(long number){

    long reverse = 0;
    while(number != 0){
        reverse = (reverse*10)+(number%10);
        number = number/10;
    } 
    return reverse;
}

public static void main(String a[]){
    System.out.println("Reversed is: "+new NumReverse().reverseNumber(103));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

compute the multiply times and add times:
suppose f(x) = an * x^n + an-1 * x^n-1 + ... + a1 * x + a0
1. If calculate f(x) by computing one item by one item,
      it will take (n+1) + n + (n-1) + ... + 1 + 0 = (n+1)(n+2)/2 multiply times and  n addition times.
2. If calculate f(x) by `n = n*10 + mod`,
it will take n multiply times and n addition times.

Of course, if `pow()` has some optimization such as "divide and conquer", the complexity of `pow()` should be O(logN).

Comment: This is speculation.  In fact, the real implementation doesn't work this way at all; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418731/java-math-powa-b-time-complexity.  But don't take my word for it: look at the source code!