# Time complexity of Math.pow(a,n) JAVA

Tags: java, performance

What is the time complexity of `math.pow(a,n)` function in java? Because when we solve the same using *recursion*, the time complexity is *O(n)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Math.pow(a,b) time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418731/java-math-powa-b-time-complexity)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the [current implementation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/91015053fcd5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/FdLibm.java#l304) of `pow`. I don't see any loops or recursion, so the complexity has to be `O(1)`:

```
   /**
     * Compute x**y
     *                    n
     * Method:  Let x =  2   * (1+f)
     *      1. Compute and return log2(x) in two pieces:
     *              log2(x) = w1 + w2,
     *         where w1 has 53 - 24 = 29 bit trailing zeros.
     *      2. Perform y*log2(x) = n+y' by simulating multi-precision
     *         arithmetic, where |y'| <= 0.5.
     *      3. Return x**y = 2**n*exp(y'*log2)
     *
     * Special cases:
     *      1.  (anything) ** 0  is 1
     *      2.  (anything) ** 1  is itself
     *      3.  (anything) ** NAN is NAN
     *      4.  NAN ** (anything except 0) is NAN
     *      5.  +-(|x| > 1) **  +INF is +INF
     *      6.  +-(|x| > 1) **  -INF is +0
     *      7.  +-(|x| < 1) **  +INF is +0
     *      8.  +-(|x| < 1) **  -INF is +INF
     *      9.  +-1         ** +-INF is NAN
     *      10. +0 ** (+anything except 0, NAN)               is +0
     *      11. -0 ** (+anything except 0, NAN, odd integer)  is +0
     *      12. +0 ** (-anything except 0, NAN)               is +INF
     *      13. -0 ** (-anything except 0, NAN, odd integer)  is +INF
     *      14. -0 ** (odd integer) = -( +0 ** (odd integer) )
     *      15. +INF ** (+anything except 0,NAN) is +INF
     *      16. +INF ** (-anything except 0,NAN) is +0
     *      17. -INF ** (anything)  = -0 ** (-anything)
     *      18. (-anything) ** (integer) is (-1)**(integer)*(+anything**integer)
     *      19. (-anything except 0 and inf) ** (non-integer) is NAN
     *
     * Accuracy:
     *      pow(x,y) returns x**y nearly rounded. In particular
     *                      pow(integer,integer)
     *      always returns the correct integer provided it is
     *      representable.
     */
    public static class Pow {
        private Pow() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public static strictfp double compute(final double x, final double y) {
            double z;
            double r, s, t, u, v, w;
            int i, j, k, n;

            // y == zero: x**0 = 1
            if (y == 0.0)
                return 1.0;

            // +/-NaN return x + y to propagate NaN significands
            if (Double.isNaN(x) || Double.isNaN(y))
                return x + y;

            final double y_abs = Math.abs(y);
            double x_abs   = Math.abs(x);
            // Special values of y
            if (y == 2.0) {
                return x * x;
            } else if (y == 0.5) {
                if (x >= -Double.MAX_VALUE) // Handle x == -infinity later
                    return Math.sqrt(x + 0.0); // Add 0.0 to properly handle x == -0.0
            } else if (y_abs == 1.0) {        // y is  +/-1
                return (y == 1.0) ? x : 1.0 / x;
            } else if (y_abs == INFINITY) {       // y is +/-infinity
                if (x_abs == 1.0)
                    return  y - y;         // inf**+/-1 is NaN
                else if (x_abs > 1.0) // (|x| > 1)**+/-inf = inf, 0
                    return (y >= 0) ? y : 0.0;
                else                       // (|x| < 1)**-/+inf = inf, 0
                    return (y < 0) ? -y : 0.0;
            }

            final int hx = __HI(x);
            int ix = hx & 0x7fffffff;

            /*
             * When x < 0, determine if y is an odd integer:
             * y_is_int = 0       ... y is not an integer
             * y_is_int = 1       ... y is an odd int
             * y_is_int = 2       ... y is an even int
             */
            int y_is_int  = 0;
            if (hx < 0) {
                if (y_abs >= 0x1.0p53)   // |y| >= 2^53 = 9.007199254740992E15
                    y_is_int = 2; // y is an even integer since ulp(2^53) = 2.0
                else if (y_abs >= 1.0) { // |y| >= 1.0
                    long y_abs_as_long = (long) y_abs;
                    if ( ((double) y_abs_as_long) == y_abs) {
                        y_is_int = 2 -  (int)(y_abs_as_long & 0x1L);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Special value of x
            if (x_abs == 0.0 ||
                x_abs == INFINITY ||
                x_abs == 1.0) {
                z = x_abs;                 // x is +/-0, +/-inf, +/-1
                if (y < 0.0)
                    z = 1.0/z;     // z = (1/|x|)
                if (hx < 0) {
                    if (((ix - 0x3ff00000) | y_is_int) == 0) {
                        z = (z-z)/(z-z); // (-1)**non-int is NaN
                    } else if (y_is_int == 1)
                        z = -1.0 * z;             // (x < 0)**odd = -(|x|**odd)
                }
                return z;
            }

            n = (hx >> 31) + 1;

            // (x < 0)**(non-int) is NaN
            if ((n | y_is_int) == 0)
                return (x-x)/(x-x);

            s = 1.0; // s (sign of result -ve**odd) = -1 else = 1
            if ( (n | (y_is_int - 1)) == 0)
                s = -1.0; // (-ve)**(odd int)

            double p_h, p_l, t1, t2;
            // |y| is huge
            if (y_abs > 0x1.00000_ffff_ffffp31) { // if |y| > ~2**31
                final double INV_LN2   =  0x1.7154_7652_b82fep0;   //  1.44269504088896338700e+00 = 1/ln2
                final double INV_LN2_H =  0x1.715476p0;            //  1.44269502162933349609e+00 = 24 bits of 1/ln2
                final double INV_LN2_L =  0x1.4ae0_bf85_ddf44p-26; //  1.92596299112661746887e-08 = 1/ln2 tail

                // Over/underflow if x is not close to one
                if (x_abs < 0x1.fffff_0000_0000p-1) // |x| < ~0.9999995231628418
                    return (y < 0.0) ? s * INFINITY : s * 0.0;
                if (x_abs > 0x1.00000_ffff_ffffp0)         // |x| > ~1.0
                    return (y > 0.0) ? s * INFINITY : s * 0.0;
                /*
                 * now |1-x| is tiny <= 2**-20, sufficient to compute
                 * log(x) by x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - x^4/4
                 */
                t = x_abs - 1.0;        // t has 20 trailing zeros
                w = (t * t) * (0.5 - t * (0.3333333333333333333333 - t * 0.25));
                u = INV_LN2_H * t;      // INV_LN2_H has 21 sig. bits
                v =  t * INV_LN2_L - w * INV_LN2;
                t1 = u + v;
                t1 =__LO(t1, 0);
                t2 = v - (t1 - u);
            } else {
                final double CP      =  0x1.ec70_9dc3_a03fdp-1;  //  9.61796693925975554329e-01 = 2/(3ln2)
                final double CP_H    =  0x1.ec709ep-1;           //  9.61796700954437255859e-01 = (float)cp
                final double CP_L    = -0x1.e2fe_0145_b01f5p-28; // -7.02846165095275826516e-09 = tail of CP_H

                double z_h, z_l, ss, s2, s_h, s_l, t_h, t_l;
                n = 0;
                // Take care of subnormal numbers
                if (ix < 0x00100000) {
                    x_abs *= 0x1.0p53; // 2^53 = 9007199254740992.0
                    n -= 53;
                    ix = __HI(x_abs);
                }
                n  += ((ix) >> 20) - 0x3ff;
                j  = ix & 0x000fffff;
                // Determine interval
                ix = j | 0x3ff00000;          // Normalize ix
                if (j <= 0x3988E)
                    k = 0;         // |x| <sqrt(3/2)
                else if (j < 0xBB67A)
                    k = 1;         // |x| <sqrt(3)
                else {
                    k = 0;
                    n += 1;
                    ix -= 0x00100000;
                }
                x_abs = __HI(x_abs, ix);

                // Compute ss = s_h + s_l = (x-1)/(x+1) or (x-1.5)/(x+1.5)

                final double BP[]    = {1.0,
                                       1.5};
                final double DP_H[]  = {0.0,
                                        0x1.2b80_34p-1};        // 5.84962487220764160156e-01
                final double DP_L[]  = {0.0,
                                        0x1.cfde_b43c_fd006p-27};// 1.35003920212974897128e-08

                // Poly coefs for (3/2)*(log(x)-2s-2/3*s**3
                final double L1      =  0x1.3333_3333_33303p-1;  //  5.99999999999994648725e-01
                final double L2      =  0x1.b6db_6db6_fabffp-2;  //  4.28571428578550184252e-01
                final double L3      =  0x1.5555_5518_f264dp-2;  //  3.33333329818377432918e-01
                final double L4      =  0x1.1746_0a91_d4101p-2;  //  2.72728123808534006489e-01
                final double L5      =  0x1.d864_a93c_9db65p-3;  //  2.30660745775561754067e-01
                final double L6      =  0x1.a7e2_84a4_54eefp-3;  //  2.06975017800338417784e-01
                u = x_abs - BP[k];               // BP[0]=1.0, BP[1]=1.5
                v = 1.0 / (x_abs + BP[k]);
                ss = u * v;
                s_h = ss;
                s_h = __LO(s_h, 0);
                // t_h=x_abs + BP[k] High
                t_h = 0.0;
                t_h = __HI(t_h, ((ix >> 1) | 0x20000000) + 0x00080000 + (k << 18) );
                t_l = x_abs - (t_h - BP[k]);
                s_l = v * ((u - s_h * t_h) - s_h * t_l);
                // Compute log(x_abs)
                s2 = ss * ss;
                r = s2 * s2* (L1 + s2 * (L2 + s2 * (L3 + s2 * (L4 + s2 * (L5 + s2 * L6)))));
                r += s_l * (s_h + ss);
                s2  = s_h * s_h;
                t_h = 3.0 + s2 + r;
                t_h = __LO(t_h, 0);
                t_l = r - ((t_h - 3.0) - s2);
                // u+v = ss*(1+...)
                u = s_h * t_h;
                v = s_l * t_h + t_l * ss;
                // 2/(3log2)*(ss + ...)
                p_h = u + v;
                p_h = __LO(p_h, 0);
                p_l = v - (p_h - u);
                z_h = CP_H * p_h;             // CP_H + CP_L = 2/(3*log2)
                z_l = CP_L * p_h + p_l * CP + DP_L[k];
                // log2(x_abs) = (ss + ..)*2/(3*log2) = n + DP_H + z_h + z_l
                t = (double)n;
                t1 = (((z_h + z_l) + DP_H[k]) + t);
                t1 = __LO(t1, 0);
                t2 = z_l - (((t1 - t) - DP_H[k]) - z_h);
            }

            // Split up y into (y1 + y2) and compute (y1 + y2) * (t1 + t2)
            double y1  = y;
            y1 = __LO(y1, 0);
            p_l = (y - y1) * t1 + y * t2;
            p_h = y1 * t1;
            z = p_l + p_h;
            j = __HI(z);
            i = __LO(z);
            if (j >= 0x40900000) {                           // z >= 1024
                if (((j - 0x40900000) | i)!=0)               // if z > 1024
                    return s * INFINITY;                     // Overflow
                else {
                    final double OVT     =  8.0085662595372944372e-0017; // -(1024-log2(ovfl+.5ulp))
                    if (p_l + OVT > z - p_h)
                        return s * INFINITY;   // Overflow
                }
            } else if ((j & 0x7fffffff) >= 0x4090cc00 ) {        // z <= -1075
                if (((j - 0xc090cc00) | i)!=0)           // z < -1075
                    return s * 0.0;           // Underflow
                else {
                    if (p_l <= z - p_h)
                        return s * 0.0;      // Underflow
                }
            }
            /*
             * Compute 2**(p_h+p_l)
             */
            // Poly coefs for (3/2)*(log(x)-2s-2/3*s**3
            final double P1      =  0x1.5555_5555_5553ep-3;  //  1.66666666666666019037e-01
            final double P2      = -0x1.6c16_c16b_ebd93p-9;  // -2.77777777770155933842e-03
            final double P3      =  0x1.1566_aaf2_5de2cp-14; //  6.61375632143793436117e-05
            final double P4      = -0x1.bbd4_1c5d_26bf1p-20; // -1.65339022054652515390e-06
            final double P5      =  0x1.6376_972b_ea4d0p-25; //  4.13813679705723846039e-08
            final double LG2     =  0x1.62e4_2fef_a39efp-1;  //  6.93147180559945286227e-01
            final double LG2_H   =  0x1.62e43p-1;            //  6.93147182464599609375e-01
            final double LG2_L   = -0x1.05c6_10ca_86c39p-29; // -1.90465429995776804525e-09
            i = j & 0x7fffffff;
            k = (i >> 20) - 0x3ff;
            n = 0;
            if (i > 0x3fe00000) {              // if |z| > 0.5, set n = [z + 0.5]
                n = j + (0x00100000 >> (k + 1));
                k = ((n & 0x7fffffff) >> 20) - 0x3ff;     // new k for n
                t = 0.0;
                t = __HI(t, (n & ~(0x000fffff >> k)) );
                n = ((n & 0x000fffff) | 0x00100000) >> (20 - k);
                if (j < 0)
                    n = -n;
                p_h -= t;
            }
            t = p_l + p_h;
            t = __LO(t, 0);
            u = t * LG2_H;
            v = (p_l - (t - p_h)) * LG2 + t * LG2_L;
            z = u + v;
            w = v - (z - u);
            t  = z * z;
            t1  = z - t * (P1 + t * (P2 + t * (P3 + t * (P4 + t * P5))));
            r  = (z * t1)/(t1 - 2.0) - (w + z * w);
            z  = 1.0 - (r - z);
            j  = __HI(z);
            j += (n << 20);
            if ((j >> 20) <= 0)
                z = Math.scalb(z, n); // subnormal output
            else {
                int z_hi = __HI(z);
                z_hi += (n << 20);
                z = __HI(z, z_hi);
            }
            return s * z;
        }
    }
```