# What is the time complexity of f(n)=(1-(1-k)^(n+1))? where k is constant

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

I solved a given recurrence solution to determine f(n) and finally got f(n)=(1-(1-k)^(n+1)). Now, what can the possible time complexity for f(n)=(1-(1-k)^(n+1))?

Comment: This is unclear.  Are you asking about the time complexity to **compute** `f(n)` using that formula?  If yes, it depends on the algorithm (i.e. the code) that you use to compute the value.  (A mathematical formula doesn't have a time complexity.  It is just a bunch of symbols.)

Comment: Then what could be the efficient algorithm for solving it?

Comment: On the other hand ... if `f(n)` is a formula for the time taken to compute something ... there is some doubt as to whether it is meaningful.

Comment: *"Then what could be the efficient algorithm for solving it?"* - That's a different question to what you asked!  And the answer depends on 1) the range for `k` and `n`, 2) whether `k` is an integer or real (or complex) number, and 3) the accuracy you require for the computed value.

Comment: The mother recurrence relation was : f(n)= (1−f(n-1))∗k+f(n-1). Here, "n" is the size of input and k is constant ranging [0,1].

Comment: Well in that case you can compute `f(n)` with `double` and `Math.pow`.  The complexity will be `O(1)` I think.

Comment: Time complexity is relevant for algorithms. Where is the algorithm?

Comment: @trincot - Based on the information provided, the algorithm to compute `f(n, k)` is (in Java) `double f(int n, double k) { return 1 - Math.pow(1 - k, n + 1); }`.  That is `O(1)`.

Comment: @StephenC, that is not in the question. I would like feedback from the Asker.

Comment: The pseudo-code in java manifested by @StephenC is what the algorithm is. And my question was how to determine the TC for executing those bunch of codes in order to calculate f(n,k).

Comment: Solving recurrence relations for time complexity: https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html Some seem not to understand that it is not about calculating f, but f is the time complexity, which has to be stated as O notation.

Answer (score -1):

<sup>(Turning the comments into an answer)</sup>

It transpires from the Michaylor's clarifying comments, that this Question *really* is about the complexity of computing the formula

> f(n, k) = 1 - (1 - k)<sup>(n + 1)</sup>

where "n" is a positive integer and "k" is a real number in the range 0 to 1.

First of all, it should be stated that formulae don't have execution times as they are not algorithms.  However, since there are no particular requirements for the precision of the result, we can compute it using the following Java code.

```
double f(int n, double k) { 
    return 1 - Math.pow(1 - k, n + 1); 
}
```

where `Math` is the standard `java.lang.Math` class.  The computational complexity of `Math.pow` in modern Java implementations is `O(1)` (see [Java Math.pow(a,b) time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418731)) so the complexity of the algorithm (expressed in Java) is also `O(1)`.

---

Notes:

1. It is not a given that the implementation of the equivalent of `pow(a, b)` will be `O(1)` in all programming languages' runtime libraries.
2. If better precision than `double` provides was required, the algorithm would need to use `BigDecimal` or equivalent.  It wouldn't necessarily be `O(1)`.
3. To illustrate the distinction between formulae and algorithms, if we were to replace `Math.pow(1 - k, n + 1)` with a naive `for` loop, that version would have a complexity of `O(n)`!

Comment: The comments state the opposite: n is the input size, the question is about O(f(n))

Comment: @Sebastian - Please interpret this for me:  " The pseudo-code in java manifested by StephenC **is what the algorithm is**. And my question was how to determine the TC for executing **those bunch of codes** in order to calculate f(n,k). " - Michaylor Riya
1