# How to pass an array of characters from Fortran to Python

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I wanted to write a function in fortran and then call it in another python program.
In order to do that, I tried to use f2py or fmodpy, but unfortunately it doesn't work. My (fortran) function takes a positive integer as an input and returns an array of characters.
Does anyone know how I could do that?

This is the file containing my function (the file is called `my_fortran_lib.f90`):

```
recursive function GenerateCompleteBinaryTreeNew(height) RESULT(treeResult)
!  This function returns the words representing a complete binary tree, producing the labels of its leaves 
!  (which are words composed of the letters {0, 1}). The height of the tree must be at least 1.
  implicit none

  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: height
  INTEGER :: i
  INTEGER :: number_entries_temp, number_entries 
  number_entries_temp = (2 ** height - 1) 
  !f2py integer :: number_entries_temp = pow(2,height-1)
  number_entries = number_entries_temp * 2
  CHARACTER(len=20), INTENT(out), DIMENSION(number_entries) :: treeResult
  CHARACTER(len=20), INTENT(inout), DIMENSION(number_entries_temp) :: treeResult_temp
  

  ! Case : height = 0
  IF (height == 0) THEN
    treeResult(1) = ""
  ! Case : height = 1
  else if (height == 1) then
    i = 1
    treeResult(1) = '0'
    treeResult(2) = '1'
  else
  ! Case : height > 1
    treeResult_temp = GenerateCompleteBinaryTreeNew(height-1)

    do i = 1, number_entries_temp
      treeResult(i) = '0' // treeResult_temp(i)
    end do
    do i = 1, number_entries_temp
      treeResult(i+  number_entries_temp) = '1' // treeResult_temp(i)
    end do
  end if
end function GenerateCompleteBinaryTreeNew
```

I tried with f2py by typing this command in the shell:

```
f2py3 -c -m myflib my_fortran_lib.f90
```

Here is the error message that I get

```
/Users/valeriano/Documents/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/f2py/f2py2e.py:719: VisibleDeprecationWarning: distutils has been deprecated since NumPy 1.26.xUse the Meson backend instead, or generate wrapperswithout -c and use a custom build script
  builder = build_backend(
running build
running config_cc
INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
INFO: build_src
INFO: building extension "myflib" sources
INFO: f2py options: []
INFO: f2py:> /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/myflibmodule.c
creating /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'my_fortran_lib.f90' (format:free)
Post-processing...
        Block: myflib
                        Block: foo
                        Block: generatecompletebinarytreenew
appenddecl: "intent" not implemented.
appenddecl: "dimension" not implemented.
In: :myflib:my_fortran_lib.f90:generatecompletebinarytreenew
analyzevars: prefix ('recursive') were not used
Applying post-processing hooks...
  character_backward_compatibility_hook
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
    Building module "myflib"...
    Generating possibly empty wrappers"
    Maybe empty "myflib-f2pywrappers.f"
        Constructing wrapper function "foo"...
          foo()
    Generating possibly empty wrappers"
    Maybe empty "myflib-f2pywrappers.f"
                Creating wrapper for Fortran function "generatecompletebinarytreenew"("generatecompletebinarytreenew")...
        Constructing wrapper function "generatecompletebinarytreenew"...
getstrlength: expected a signature of a string but got: {'typespec': 'character', 'charselector': {'len': '20'}, 'attrspec': [], 'intent': ['out'], 'dimension': ['number_entries']}
          generatecompletebinarytreenew = generatecompletebinarytreenew(height)
    Wrote C/API module "myflib" to file "/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/myflibmodule.c"
    Fortran 77 wrappers are saved to "/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/myflib-f2pywrappers.f"
INFO:   adding '/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/fortranobject.c' to sources.
INFO:   adding '/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9' to include_dirs.
copying /Users/valeriano/Documents/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c -> /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9
copying /Users/valeriano/Documents/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.h -> /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9
INFO:   adding '/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/myflib-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
INFO: build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
INFO: customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
INFO: get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu95', 'nag', 'nagfor', 'absoft', 'ibm', 'intel', 'gnu', 'g95', 'pg']'
INFO: customize Gnu95FCompiler
INFO: Found executable /usr/local/bin/gfortran
INFO: customize Gnu95FCompiler
INFO: customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
INFO: building 'myflib' extension
INFO: compiling C sources
INFO: C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -ftrapping-math

creating /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/var
creating /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/var/folders
creating /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/var/folders/l9
creating /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn
creating /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T
creating /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a
creating /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9
INFO: compile options: '-DNPY_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION=1 -I/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9 -I/Users/valeriano/Documents/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/valeriano/Documents/.venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
INFO: clang: /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/myflibmodule.c
INFO: clang: /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/fortranobject.c
/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/myflibmodule.c:312:43: error: use of undeclared identifier 'number_entries'
    generatecompletebinarytreenew_Dims[0]=number_entries;
                                          ^
1 error generated.
error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -ftrapping-math -DNPY_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION=1 -I/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9 -I/Users/valeriano/Documents/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/valeriano/Documents/.venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/myflibmodule.c -o /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/myflibmodule.o -MMD -MF /var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/var/folders/l9/5sv8cvgs649f75m12cv86vd80000gn/T/tmp7_xnuf2a/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/myflibmodule.o.d" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: This does not work for an unfortunate reason in f2py. The f2py maintainers do not even consider it to be a bug... See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5506 I highly suggest to take the [tour] and read [ask]. It is important to always include the error message and to search for the error message on the web and on Stack Overflow specifically.

Comment: @ewokx Thank you. If I run the function in fortran it works, but if i try to use f2py i get the messages that I added to the question, that unfortunately i do not understand

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I wanted to add the error message, but it doesn't seem to be meaningful, next time I'll add it. i tried to check for error messages in the web and found people mentioning that f2py does not accept arrays of char, but assuming that they were right, i was hoping that there were other solutions

Comment: Please see the duplicate link for the explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156750/f2py-invalid-type-argument-of-unary  However, it seems you actually got a different error message than what I got. But certainly do test the suggested workarounds first. If they do not help, show the new code and the question can be reopened.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I tried the solution of the other question, if i understood correctly in that case the problem was the power operations and the solution was to add a comment for f2py giving it directions on how to proceed. i tried, but it didn't make progress.

Comment: OK, let's reopen the question. I still think that the linked problem is really relevant, but it is not clear how to make a way around the problem. The error message I am getting is `error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
   generatecompletebinarytreenew_Dims[0]=2 ** height;` which clearly points to the issue of the power operator in the array dimension.

Comment: It is quite possible that this kind of code is not supported by f2py. Unfortunately, f2py is not really a universal tool to interface all legal Fortran code. It is made for NumPy and SciPy to interface the simpler old libraries they need. They  don't really care too much about anything else and they are actually getting rid of a lot of Fortran in the SciPy code base instead. Consider trying ctypes instead.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Thank you for the advice, I'll keep checking if the linked question can help me making progress

Comment: Check if your code compiles using your Fortran compiler.  You probably need to create a dynamically sized array to return instead of creating one on the stack.   A stack based array will get wiped on return. gfortran doesn't allow array declarations after the first executable statement - maybe your compiler is different.

Comment: @cup yes yes, i first wrote the program in fortran and tested it with gfortran, with that program it worked well.