# Is there a reason why the shift operators (>> and <<) don't work on BitwiseOperationsType?

Tags: swift, generics, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I was thinking of making an integer power function in Swift based on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101613/376683):

```
func **<T : IntegerType>(var base: T, var exponent: T) -> T {
    var result: T = 1

    assert(exponent >= 0, "Exponent cannot be negative")

    while exponent > 0 {
        if exponent & 1 != 0 {
            result *= base
        }

        exponent = exponent >> 1

        base *= base
    }

    return result
}
```

I figured I could use generics to implement the function so that it would work with any integer type.

Unfortunately, I get an error when I attempt to use `exponent >> 1`:

> Binary operator '>>' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands

Checking the function definitions for `>>`, I see that there is one for each of the ten integer types, but no other ones are defined. I was surprised therefore that all the other operators were working, such as `&`, but I noticed that `&` was actually defined to work on all types which conform to `BitwiseOperationsType`, which `IntegerType` appears to conform to.

Is there a reason why the `>>` and `<<` operators are not implemented for `BitwiseOperationsType`?

Comment: Wouldn't `exponent /= 2` do the same thing?

Comment: I think you're correct (and it seems to work!) Still, I'd be interested to know why it doesn't work with the shift operators.

Comment: Discussed here: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160118/006908.html.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, that pretty much contains everything I wanted to know!

Comment: Most likely, it was asked two years ago. I think the issue has since been resolved.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't checked the date.