# need to write a division expression in c language

Tags: c, codeblocks

How to define such an expression in c language :

```
x+(x^2)/(2*2-1)
```

where `x` is a real number.

I tried to enter the expression as it is but that didn't help.

the thing is I don't want to use any self-defined functions, just loops.

any ideas anyone?

Comment: The '/' operator is the correct operator for representing division.  When you say "that didn't help" what do you mean?  What error did you get?

Comment: maybe the operator error is with '^'?

Comment: In C, the caret `^`  is the bitwise xor operator, which can only operate on integer types. There is no power operator, but you can calculate x² as `x*x` or use `pow(x, 2)` from `<math.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `^` is the bitwise XOR operator. There is no "power of" operator.

So the C equivalent would look like this:

```
x+(x*x)/(2*2-1)
```

Operator precedence is just as for math, so note that the above is equivalent to

```
x + ( (x*x) / ((2*2)-1) )
```

If you need a variable "raise x to the power of y", there is unfortunately only the `pow()` function, which works on floating point variables, and is therefore somewhat bloated and inefficient. However, writing your own integer version of it is trivial, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int).

Comment: thanks for noting this out rally helpful and part of what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in code, you will have to lay ground for displaying the result of what you want. Typing expressions "as is" into c code will do nothing for you. Here is an example of a simple c program that will do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
int x, result;
x = 10; // x is 10 for this example, but you may assign any number where both x and result are within the range of integers
result = x + ( x * x ) / ( 2 * 2 - 1 );
printf("The result is : %d", result);
return 0;
}
```

The key points here are:

- a ^ 2 in c programming does not represent computing the power, its a
  bitwise XOR instead.
- a ^ 2 can be simplified to a * a through basic mathematics.
- to compute a number in c you need to actually compute it, not just
  calculate it (the printf statement for instance prints this to the
  console from which the program is run in my example)