# Passing a non-associative function to reduce

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My program has this line:

```
Function<String, Integer> f = (String s) -> s.chars().reduce(0, (a, b) -> 2 * a + b);
```

The function being passed to reduce is not associative. Reduce's documentation says that the function passed must be associative.

How can I rewrite this as an expression which doesn't break reduce's contract?

Comment: You can't. Just use a goold old loop.

Comment: Are you talking about the function `f` or `(a, b) -> 2 * a + b`? if it's `f`, I think it's safe to use it in any parallel stream; if it's `(a, b) -> 2`, it will be ok too because i don't see any reason to do: `s.chars().parallel().reduce(0, (a, b) -> 2 * a + b)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Under the current* implementation and *IFF you are not going to use parallel* - you are safe with what you have right now. Obviously if you are OK with these disclaimers.

Or you can obviously create the function with a for loop:

```
 Function<String, Integer> f = s -> {
        int first = s.charAt(0) * 2 + s.charAt(1);
        int total = first;

        for (int x = 1; x < s.length() - 1; x++) {
            total = total * 2 + s.charAt(x + 1);
        }

        return total;

    };
```

Comment: It's really the 'under the current implementation' part that bothers me. The Java devs have pacifically reserved the right to change how this works.

Comment: Pacifically? You mean as opposed to having a fight over it?

Comment: @NickODell yeah, that's the bitter part. You can still create a `Function` out of that with a simple for loop (edited the post)

Comment: @NickODell you can even do a `boxed.reduce(three-arguments)` and simply throw an `Exception` for the merger that will get invoked for parallel computation; but *even that* is not guaranteed to be used *only* for parallel processing but the spec

Comment: @Eugene That one still requires that the second argument be associative. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Comment: @NickODell I know, my point was that you can *explicitly* prohibit parallelization this way

Comment: This looks very much like the hash code algorithm, except that it uses `2` instead of `31`. So generally, it’s possible to parallelize, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396614/2711488), but for most use cases, you surely want to stick to the loop. But why aren’t you simply using `s -> { int total = 0;      for(int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++) total = total * 2 + s.charAt(x);     return total; };`?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert this function to an associative function, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396614/2711488) at the example of `List.hashCode()`. The difference lies only in the factor (`2`vs.`31`) and the start value (`1`vs.`0`).

It can be adapted to your task, which is especially easy when you have a random access input like a `String`:

```
Function<String, Integer> f =
    s -> IntStream.range(0, s.length()).map(i -> s.charAt(i)<<(s.length()-i-1)).sum();
```

This would even run in parallel, but it’s unlikely that you ever encounter such humongous strings that a parallel evaluation provides a benefit. So what remains, is that most people might consider this solution less readable than a simple `for` loop…

---

Note that the above solution exhibits a different overflow behavior, i.e. if the `String` has more than 32 `char`s, due to the usage of the shift operator rather than multiplying with two.
The fix for this issue makes the solution even more efficient:

```
Function<String, Integer> f = s ->
    IntStream.range(Math.max(0, s.length()-32), s.length())
             .map(i -> s.charAt(i)<<(s.length()-i-1)).sum();
```

If the string has more than 32 `char`s, it only processes the last 32 `char`s, which is already sufficient to calculate the same result as your original function.

Comment: I actually am writing a hash function - I was trying to provide a simple, self-contained, example. Thank you for the link to the other question - I thought I searched for duplicates well enough, but apparently not.