# String hashCode() documentation vs implementation

Tags: java, string, java-8, hashcode

Below is the source code snippet of `String.hashCode()` method from Java 8 (1.8.0_131 to be precise)

```
/**
 * Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a
 * {@code String} object is computed as
 * <blockquote><pre>
 * s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
 * </pre></blockquote>
 * using {@code int} arithmetic, where {@code s[i]} is the
 * <i>i</i>th character of the string, {@code n} is the length of
 * the string, and {@code ^} indicates exponentiation.
 * (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)
 *
 * @return  a hash code value for this object.
 */
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

You can see that, the documentation says, that `hashCode()` is computed using below formula

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

while the actual implementation is different

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    h = 31 * h + val[i];
}
```

Am I missing any obvious thing? Please help me.

Comment: What Java version are you using? I see a slightly different implementation (though still none conforming to the documentation).

Comment: @Turing85 It is mentioned as Java 8

Comment: @Turing85 its `1.8.0_131` to be precise

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implementation is correct, with the caveat that integer overflow may occur (which is ok here, it doesn't harm anything). It's using [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) for polynomial evaluation.

Here's the steps on a sample string "CAT".

```
h = 0
```

First loop:

```
i = 0
h = 31 * 0 + 'C' (67) = 67
```

Second loop:

```
i = 1
h = 31 * 67 + 'A' (65) = 2142
```

Third loop:

```
i = 2
h = 31 * 2142 + 'T' (84) = 66486
```

Let's derive the formula from the code.  Here, *n* is the index of `i` into the string *s*.  Each iteration of the `for` loop performs this formula.

h<sub>n</sub> = 31h<sub>n-1</sub> + s<sub>n</sub>

```
h0 /* after loop i = 0 */ = s[0]
h1 /* after loop i = 1 */ = 31*h0 + s[1] = 31*s[0] + s[1]
h2 /* after loop i = 2 */ = 31*h1 + s[2] = 31*(31*s[0] + s[1]) + s[2]
h = 31*31*s[0] + 31*s[1] + s[2]
```

The exponents you see for the powers of 31 arise because each loop multiplies in another factor of `31` before adding the value of the next character.

Comment: See also [Strength reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction). As an addendum, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396614/2711488) does the opposite. `List.hashCode` has been specified in terms of the multiplying loop and I transformed it into the sum of exponentiations to make it parallelizable.

Answer (score 5):

It is easiest to see what happens with some example. Let's take a String `s` of length `n` and all notation as above. We will analyze the loop iteration for iteration. We will call `h_old` the value `h` has at the beginning of the current iteration and `h_new` the value `h` has at the end of the current iteration. It is easy to see that `h_new` of iteration `i` will be `h_old` of iteration `i + 1`.

```
╔═════╦════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ It. ║ h_old                      ║ h_new                                           ║
╠═════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1   ║ 0                          ║ 31*h_old + s[0] =                               ║
║     ║                            ║          s[0]                                   ║
║     ║                            ║                                                 ║
║ 2   ║ s[0]                       ║ 31*h_old + s[1] =                               ║
║     ║                            ║ 31      *s[0] +          s[1]                   ║
║     ║                            ║                                                 ║
║ 3   ║ 31  *s[0] +    s[1]        ║ 31^2    *s[0] + 31      *s[1] +    s[2]         ║
║     ║                            ║                                                 ║
║ 4   ║ 31^2*s[0] + 31*s[1] + s[2] ║ 31^3    *s[0] + 31^2    *s[1] + 31*s[2] + s[3]  ║
║ :   ║ :                          ║ :                                               ║
║ n   ║ ...                        ║ 31^(n-1)*s[0] + 31^(n-2)*s[1] + ... + 31^0*s[n] ║
╚═════╩════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

(Table generated with [Senseful](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/))

The powers of `31` are created through the loop and the constant multiplication of `h` with `31` (making use of the [distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of the multiplication).
As we can see in the last row of the table, this is exactly what the documentation said it would be.