# C++ Error on sum of integers

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem. I give it string `"BC"` and it outputs 54 not 55
as in first cycle `num = 3` and in second `num = 52` but the sum is `54` why? 
Can you help me?

```
string getX(string x) {
    int ans = 0, num;
    for (int i = 0, j = x.size() - 1; i < x.size(), j >= 0; i++, j--) {
        num = x[j] - 64;
        num = num * pow(26, i);
        ans += num;
    }
    return to_string(ans);
}
```

Comment: Off topic: `i <= x.size() - 1;` can be accomplished with `i < x.size();`

Comment: You don't need to cast `(int)num`, since `num` is already declared to be `int`.

Comment: Yeah I know. I have done This too `for (int i = 0, j = x.size() - 1; i < x.size(), j >= 0; i++, j--)`

Comment: `pow(26, i)` may give you a few surprises. `pow` returns `double` which may not be exact.

Comment: `pow` computes in floating point. The result could be approximated like `54.999999999`. When casted into `int` during `+=` operation, the result could be `54`.

Comment: This can probably be solved by calling `round()` on `pow`'s returned value.

Comment: better write `num = x[j] - 'A' - 1;` if you don't know ASCII codes by heart

Comment: Prefer to use character constants, like `x[j] - 'A'`, rather than their ASCII decimal numbers.

Comment: there's a good integer power function somewhere on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int

Comment: @Franck While that's theoretically possible, does it really happen when both inputs are integers? I guess it would happen if the implementation uses logarithms to calculate it.

Comment: @Barmar I agree. It shouldn't. I have not reproduced it. On my machine result is 55. `pow(26, 1)` should be 26: no approximation, but in theory it depends from the libc++.

Comment: I think your  `i < x.size(), j >= 0` edit may have made things weirder. The comma operator will evaluate and discard `i < x.size()` and then use `j >= 0` as intended.

Comment: @user4581301 That's OK, because either of them is a valid test.

Comment: @Barmar that's why I went with "weirder". It works, but it's weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`round(pow(26,i))` Helped. Thank you @MrPromethee

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `pow` function.  Multipy by 26, then add:

```
unsigned int num = 0U;
for (j = 0; j < x.size(); ++j)
{
  num = num * 26;
  num += (x[j] - 'A');
}
```