# Error: 'Math' undeclared first use in this function

Tags: c, undeclared-identifier

I keep getting this error:

> 'Math' undeclared first use in this function

although I included the math library.

```
int x = Math.pow(10.0,(double)k);
```

This is the line where I get the error, any ideas why?

Comment: C doesn't have packages or namespaces... it's `pow`, and include `math.h`

Comment: @Yasmin12  Just remove Math.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and link with `-lm`

Comment: @yoones: you're right, but I found out that it was no longer necessary on latest versions of gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pow` is part of the math library, but there are no namespaces or packages in C.

So first

```
#include <math.h>
```

then call as:

```
int x = pow(10.0,k);
```

Old versions of `gcc` require you to add `-lm` when linking, although this is unnecessary with latest versions (version 6 doesn't require it anymore).

note that there's no need to cast `k` as a `double`, and also, you may have loss of precision by storing your result in an `int` (truncating)

Also note that if you're doing that to get an integer power of `10`, you'd better use integer multiplication in a loop (there are even better algorithms, but still integers, like [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int))

Answer (score 1):

First You need to include **math library** before main like

```
#include <math.h>
```

Then just use Your code as

```
int x= pow(10.0,(double)k);
```