# Cannot initialize integer

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have a method `loading`:

```
-(void)loading:(MKTileOverlayPath)path ... {
...
```

Within this method I am trying to calculate something

```
NSInteger *a = pow(2, path.z) - path.y - 1;
```

I get an error:

> Initializing 'NSInteger *' (aka 'long *') with an expression of incompatible type 'double'

Why is that double? path.z and path.y are, as stated in the [documentation MKTileOverlayPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlaypath?language=objc), *integer*. And `pow(2, path.z)` cannot result in an `float` or `double` neither, when there are only `integers`... Why is that?

Comment: why is this tagged with `c++` and `c` ?

Comment: Looks like you are using the c version of [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) which only accepts `double` and returns `double`.

Comment: @Raxvan I am pretty new to `objective-c`, but I thought that this is a part of the langauge which could be coming from `c/c++`.

Comment: The `double` type in the error message is a red herring.  You are tying to assign a pointer to a non pointer, that's the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver Where am I trying this?

Comment: @Stophface with `NSInteger *a`.  `a` is a pointer to a `NSInteger`

Comment: @NathanOliver How would I write it instead? I am a little los there. How to write the line that it works?! 
`NSInteger *resultInt = (int)pow((double)2, (double)path.z) - path.y - 1;` seems not the right way...

Comment: @Stophface `NSInteger a`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh Dear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically it won't result in a non-integer value, but that's not the contract for the `pow()` function.  According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/, the parameters are being implicitly cast to doubles and the return value of the function is always a double.

Comment: I am a little los there. How to write the line that it works?! 
`NSInteger *resultInt = (int)pow((double)2, (double)path.z) - path.y - 1;` seems not the right way...

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors:

1. The standard C `pow()` produces a `double` and it's parameters are also `double` - your integer arguments are implicitly cast for you. There is no version for integer types. The best solution is *not* to use casts to get an integer value, that introduces the possibility of errors doe to the nature of floating-point math, but to simply write your own integer power function. You can copy the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int) - just implement it using the integer type (`int`, `long` etc.) you require.
2. You have confused your variable type, object types are *reference types* and declared as pointers, e.g. `NSString *`; simple numeric types are *value types* and are not pointers, e.g. `NSInteger`.