# Sin algorithm not working

Tags: c++, math, visual-c++, trigonometry

I made a c++ program that calculates sin without math.h. Im using this algorithm for my program https://ibb.co/bTnQnS. I enter 45 degrees, the program converts degrees to radians, the program uses the algorithm, and the program outputs -0.868597. The program should output 0.70710678 or √2/2. What am I doing wrong with the algorithm?

**Code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double sin(int input, int decimal_count);
int factorial(int n);
double deg_to_rad(int deg);
double power(double base, int power);


int main(){
    double angle;
    int decimal;

    cout << sin(45,8) << endl;

    //end
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

double sin(int input, int accuracy) {
    int odds = 3;
    double sin;
    double rads = deg_to_rad(input);

    for (int i = 1; i <= accuracy; i += 1) {


        if (i==1) {
            sin = power(rads, odds) / factorial(odds);
        }
        else if (i%2==0) { 
            sin = (power(rads, odds) / factorial(odds)) + sin; 

        }
        else {
            sin = (power(rads, odds) / factorial(odds)) - sin;

        }
        odds = odds + 2;

    }
    sin = sin - rads;
    return sin;
}



int factorial(int n) {
    int fact = 1;

    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j+=1) {
        fact = fact * j;
    }
    return fact;
}



double deg_to_rad(int deg) {
    return deg*(3.14159265/180);
}


double power(double base, int power) {
    double ans = 1;

    for (int k = 1; k <= power; k+=1) {
        ans = ans * base;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: are you using Taylor's series to calculate sine?

Comment: Your code looks very different from the formula you claim to implement...

Comment: Were do you add `x` ? I mean sin(x) = x - x^3/3! ...

Comment: Where is x? It doesn't exist in the code.

Comment: @LoganPaul you are using radians, not degrees. sin(45 degrees) is 1/sqrt(2)

Comment: @LoganPaul sin(45 radians) = .85..., sin(45 degres) = .70...

Comment: note that your power function is also [not efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101613/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your taylor series expansion function is incorrect. :)

you have to disregard all even terms.

I have fixed it for you (i removed some windows specific stuff as I don;t have a windows machine: the `stdfax.h` header and the calls to `pause` were removed)

```
# include <cstdlib>
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double sin(int input, int decimal_count);
int factorial(int n);
double deg_to_rad(int deg);
double power(double base, int power);


int main(){
    double angle;
    int decimal;

    cout << "The sine value is: " << sin(45,8) << endl;

    //end
    system("sleep 2");
    return 0;
}

double sin(int input, int accuracy) {
    int odds = 3;
    double sin;
    double rads = deg_to_rad(input);
    bool negative_flag = true;
    cout << "You entered " << input << " degrees" << endl;
    cout << "This is " << rads << " radians" << endl;
    sin = rads;

    for (int taylor_term = 3; taylor_term <= 7; taylor_term += 2) {
        double term = (double)(power(rads, taylor_term) / factorial(taylor_term));
        if (negative_flag) {
            term = -1 * term;
        }
        negative_flag = !(negative_flag);
        sin += term;
    }
    return sin;
}



int factorial(int n) {
    int fact = 1;

    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j+=1) {
        fact = fact * j;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

Running this output

```
You entered 45 degrees
This is 0.785398 radians
The sine value is: 0.707106
```

#### Explanation

The taylor series expansion for sine is a series of terms with odd taylor's coefficients that alternate  in sign. In my code the alternating signs is effected by the flag. I've also taken into account only the first 3 terms of the taylor series expansion.

Other than that, the line `double term = (double)(power(rads, taylor_term) / factorial(taylor_term));` calculates every term in the taylor series expansion.

`negative_flag = !(negative_flag);` resets the flag sign for the next term.

#### Addressing your comment and where your code was a bit wrong

Below is your sin func with minimal changes to make it work.
What you were doing wrong

***These are just minimal edits, performing these edits would naturally be followed up with some code style cleanup. eg: the `if` and `else` block(not `else if`) have almost the exact same code***

1. sin was not being initialized before being modified
2. the attribution to correct signs the taylor terms in the `if` blocks was not correct.
3. the extra subtraction of `rads` at the end from `sin` was not required. Once these things were fixed, your code works :)

   ```
   int odds = 3;
   double sin ;
   double rads = deg_to_rad(input);
   sin = rads;

   for (int i = 1; i <= accuracy; i += 1) {


       if (i==1) {
           sin = sin - power(rads, odds) / factorial(odds);
       }
       else if (i%2==0) {
           sin = (power(rads, odds) / factorial(odds)) + sin;

       }
       else {
           sin = -(power(rads, odds) / factorial(odds)) + sin;

       }
       odds = odds + 2;

   }
   return sin;
   ```

Comment: You don't need the `negative_flag` at all.  All you need is to flip between `1` and -`1` and multiply by that value. `double multiplier = 1.0; ...for(...) {... sin += term * multiplier; multiplier *= -1; }`

Comment: @Srini Doesnt my "odds" variable skip all even numbers? Why didn't my function work?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes that seems a bit cleaner :)

Comment: @Johanson151 I've edited my answer to provide some more explanation about what you were doing wrong :)

Comment: @Srini Thank you very much! You were very helpful!

Comment: You don't need factorial and power at all. Since you're iterating over the term ordinal, it is possible to incrementally calculate next term in the series by simple multiplication/division.

Comment: That's a great observation and a good suggestion for optimization.