# No argument variadic template function in C++

Tags: c++, function, variadic-templates

```
template <bool ...T> 
int some_function()
{
  // this is the function with return type int
  // I am not sure how to get the values into the function
}

// this is how I want to call the function
int temp = some_function<1,0,0,0>();
```

Any suggestion for the function declaration?

Comment: The code you have shown looks correct.  Are you asking how to use the values in `T...`?

Comment: Yes, that is the question I am asking for. How can I use the values in T...?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them.  Can you should what you would like your function to do with them?

Comment: It seems you are looking for https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold  basic demonstration is here https://godbolt.org/z/hV4KdZ

Comment: Those are the binary version of the actual decimal number. I want to reconstruct the decimal number with those binaries. I assume that I can do it when I get those binary numbers somehow!

Comment: @arnes but I need the values in T..., is there ant way to get those? I want to play with the numbers in it.

Comment: Won't writing `0b1000` for the number be simpler?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I must do it with the long way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your use case, you can use recursion to do what you want.  To do that you need two overloads.  One with just a single bool parameter, and another with two bool parameters plus the variadic part.  That gives you access to each value individually as you recurse your way through the parameter pack.  In this case that would look like

```
// quick and dirty pow fucntion.  There are better ones out there like https://stackoverflow.com/a/101613/4342498
template <typename T, typename U>
auto pow(T base, U exp)
{
    T ret = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp; ++i)
        ret *= base;
    return ret;
}

template <bool Last>
int some_function()
{
    return Last;
}

template <bool First, bool Second, bool... Rest> 
int some_function()
{
    return First * pow(2, sizeof...(Rest) + 1) + some_function<Second, Rest...>();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << some_function<1,0,0,0>();
}
```

Which outputs:

```
8
```

Comment: This is the answer I am searching for; however;I need some modification on the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @erkus19 No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

> Those are the binary version of the actual decimal number. I want to reconstruct the decimal number with those binaries.

While you can perhaps do this more performantly, `std::bitset` offers a pretty straightforward solution ([live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/uX4pFk)):

```
template <bool ...T> 
int some_function()
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(T) < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT); // We want this to fit in int with no negatives.

    char binary[]{(T + '0')...}; // Put corresponding '0's and '1's into a string.
    std::bitset<sizeof...(T)> bits(binary); // Use the string to make a bitset.
    return bits.to_ulong(); // Convert the bitset to a number.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Those are the binary version of the actual decimal number. I want to reconstruct the decimal number with those binaries. I assume that I can do it when I get those binary numbers somehow!

If you can use C++17, so also folding, I suppose you can write something as follows

```
template <bool ...T> 
int some_function ()
 {
   int ret{};

   return ((ret <<= 1, ret += T), ...);
 }
```

In C++11 and C++14 is a little less elegant

```
template <bool ...T> 
int some_function ()
 {
   using unused = int[];

   int ret{};

   (void)unused { 0, (ret <<= 1, ret += T)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried both of them and they work pretty well. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Since I have already select the solutions above, I cannot select your solution as a correct one.

Comment: @erkus19 - is enough if you find it interesting.