# why the answer is coming garbage value?

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define fastio ios::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
#define ll long long
#define M 1000000007
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fastio;
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        long n,a;
        cin >> n >> a;
        ll ans=0,x=a,y;
        for(long i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            y=pow(x,(2*i-1));
            ans=(ans%M+y%M)%M;
            x=(x*y)%M;
        }
        cout << ans << "\n";
    }
}
```

Given this input

```
1
4 10
```

I'm getting a garbage value back. Why is that?

However, for this input:

```
1
3 2
```

The answer I'm getting back seems totally fine.

Comment: One possible problem:  `pow()` uses floating-point math (i.e. it takes `double` arguments and returns a `double` result) rather than `long long` integer math, which means that its results are susceptible to all the usual floating-point roundoff-error problems.  You might want to use your own `ipow()` function instead to avoid that complication (see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int )

Comment: What garbage are you referring to? Also, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h and use don't use macro for useless stuff, like `ll` could be a typedef...

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: Use your debugger to narrow down the problem.

Comment: What is this code suppose to do? what do you expect out respect to what you put in? we need this information to help you debug

Comment: *Here for input: 1 4 10 garbage value is coming why?* -- If you know the input that fails, why are you not putting that input into the code itself?  There should be no `cin` statements in the code you posted -- you should be assigning the variables with the faulty test case.  Remember that we are not the online judge website -- you should take the code, remove all of the stuff like "sync_with_stdio", use the proper headers, get rid of the crazy macros like `ll`, and if you know the test data, *put the test data in the program by assigning the variables with the test data*.

Comment: You need to improve your coding standards or guidelines.  This style of code would not pass a professional code inspection.  If you are doing the online exercises for education, you should employ good coding styles.

Comment: This is pretty standard USACO solution code style.

Comment: @Aplet123 This is not an online competition [to produce the worst possible code in the least possible time], it is a Q&A for professional developers. So some translation is required. OP can always convert it back before submission, after locating their bug.

Comment: @OP [This is what should have been posted](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55ad80501d5e2b40).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the correct output should be, But it looks like you have an overflow. In `pow` function you calculate the whole result then take the mod. Since the result may be very big to even fit in `long long`, it overflows before taking the mod, thus having a wrong answer. A simple solution to this is to implement a `Pow` function that takes the mod whenever it multiplies. The code have some other problems such as importing `bits/stdc++.h`, `using namespace std`, `ll` and `M`.... but that's irrelevant. But I suppose this code is for some problem solving contest.

Code with the problem probably solved:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define fastio ios::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
#define ll long long
#define M 1000000007
using namespace std;

long long Pow(int n, int p)
{
    if (p == 0) return 1;

    auto res = Pow(n, p / 2);

    res *= res;
    res %= M;

    if (p % 2 == 1)
        res *= n, res %= M;

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    fastio;
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        long n,a;
        cin >> n >> a;
        ll ans=0,x=a,y;
        for(long i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            y=Pow(x,(2*i-1));
            ans=(ans%M+y%M)%M;
            x=(x*y)%M;
        }
        cout << ans << "\n";
    }
}
```

Input:

```
1 4 10
```

Output:

```
707919736
```