# How to use Math.Pow with integers in Golang

Tags: go, floating-point, type-conversion, integer

I keep getting the error:

```
cannot use a (type int) as type float64 in argument to math.Pow, cannot use x (type int) as type float64 in argument to math.Pow, 
invalid operation: math.Pow(a, x) % n (mismatched types float64 and int)
```

```
func pPrime(n int) bool {
    var nm1 int = n - 1
    var x int = nm1/2
    a := 1;
    for  a < n {
        if  (math.Pow(a, x)) % n == nm1 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: [Convert your ints to floats](https://tour.golang.org/basics/13) for use in a function that takes floats.

Comment: Am I the only one surprised of seeing Go does not have an integer `math.Pow`? As a newbie, it makes me question whether to switch to other languages.

Answer (score 18):

```
func powInt(x, y int) int {
    return int(math.Pow(float64(x), float64(y)))
}
```

In case you have to reuse it and keep it a little more clean.

Comment: while this keeps things cleaner, I think you'd be better to avoid using `math.Pow` entirely if you're going to write your own function that accepts `int` arguments and returns `int`. As I mention in my answer, using a loop to do the multiplication yourself results in performance improvements, plus you remove the external package dependency

Answer (score 13):

If your inputs are `int` and the output is always expected to be `int`, then you're dealing with 32-bit numbers. It's more efficient to write your own function to handle this multiplication rather than using `math.Pow`. `math.Pow`, as mentioned in the other answers, expects 64-bit values.

Here's a Benchmark comparison for 15^15 (which approaches the upper limits for 32-bit representation):

```golang
// IntPow calculates n to the mth power. Since the result is an int, it is assumed that m is a positive power
func IntPow(n, m int) int {
    if m == 0 {
        return 1
    }

    if m == 1 {
        return n
    }

    result := n
    for i := 2; i <= m; i++ {
        result *= n
    }
    return result
}

// MathPow calculates n to the mth power with the math.Pow() function
func MathPow(n, m int) int {
    return int(math.Pow(float64(n), float64(m)))
}
```

The result:

```golang
go test -cpu=1 -bench=.
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: pow
BenchmarkIntPow15   195415786            6.06 ns/op
BenchmarkMathPow15  40776524            27.8 ns/op
```

I believe the best *solution* is that you should write your own function similar to `IntPow(m, n int)` shown above. My benchmarks show that it runs more than 4x faster on a single CPU core compared to using `math.Pow`.

Comment: How would you deal with pows to the power of a negative number? e.g: 2 ^ -1

Comment: @cesartalves the expected result wouldn't be an integer, so casting the values as `float64` and using `math.Pow` would be appropriate if there are negative exponents involved

Comment: Makes sense. I would just improve on the answer by allowing the value of 0 to be passed to `m`, since  `x ^ 0 = 1` :)

Comment: ah I see what you're saying. I'll elaborate on the `IntPow()` description to clarify constraints

Comment: It's terrible that Go would not include IntPow. Your implementation is linear in time complexity whereas decent standard library should provide trivial implementation with logarithmic complexity.

Answer (score 11):

Since nobody mentioned an efficient way (logarithmic) to do `Pow(x, n)` for integers `x` and `n` is as follows if you want to implement it yourself:

```
// Assumption: n >= 0
func PowInts(x, n int) int {
   if n == 0 { return 1 }
   if n == 1 { return x }
   y := PowInts(x, n/2)
   if n % 2 == 0 { return y*y }
   return x*y*y
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While the above answer by Eissa for an efficient solution is technically correct, the recursion probably kills the performance. See [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int) for a more optimal solution. Here's the C solution translated to Go:

```
func IntPow(base, exp int) int {
    result := 1
    for {
        if exp & 1 == 1 {
            result *= base
        }
        exp >>= 1
        if exp == 0 {
            break
        }
        base *= base
    }

    return result
}
```

In my benchmarking this is nearly twice as fast as the recursive version.

Comment: Pedantic: The "C" solution would use `exp & 1 == 1` --> `exp % 2` and `exp >>= 1` to `exp /= 2` to correctly handle all 3 possible `int` encodings and let the compiler emit efficient code.  Of course `exp < 0` remains a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the exact exponentiation of integers, use [(*big.Int).Exp](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Exp). You're likely to overflow int64 pretty quickly with powers larger than two.