# Why does 10 digits number become 9,999,999,999?

Tags: c

Here is my code for getting the root of 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned long long root(int n);
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    unsigned long long c;
    n=10;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        c=root(i);
        printf("%d decimal digits:%llu\n",i,c);
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned long long root(int n)
{   unsigned long long int m,d;
    d=pow(10,n);
    m=2*pow(10,2*n);
    while (pow(d,2)<=m)
    {
        d++;
    }
    return d-1;

}
```

Unsigned long long int can support from 0 to $2^64-1$.
I think this enough to calculate 10 digits decimal.

I expect the output of 10 digits decimal should be **14142135623**

Comment: What is the actual output of your program? What is the expected output? Have you tried to step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Also, `pow` returns a `double` which can vastly exceed the storage of `unsigned long long` causing the result to be reduced modulo until it fits in either `d` or `m`. (in your case the limit of `10` should keep things in range -- but if you change `n` be aware...)

Comment: `pow` is meant for floating point powers, not integer powers.  `double` only has 53 bits of precision.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int may interest you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `10` digits decimal should be `14142135623`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You're actually going to `10 ** 20`, not `10 ** 10`, because of this line, which uses `2 * n` (where the `n` you pass goes to `10`):

   ```
   m=2*pow(10,2*n);
   ```

   So even ignoring your other issue, this wouldn't work (`2 ** 64` isn't enough to handle 20 digits).
2. `pow` is implemented in terms of `double`, and `double` typically only has 53 bits of integer precision. So you're not actually getting 64 bits of precision.

If you want to do integer exponentiation with numbers beyond what `double` can accurately represent, you'll need to write your own integer-based `pow`.

Comment: I just want 15 digits.

Comment: @kile: Yeah, standard IEEE 754 binary floating point (what `double` is typically implemented as) can't reach the top end of 15 digits. So you can't use `pow`. Write your own integer `pow`. Or just move to using GMP and avoid the limitations of C standard types.