# C can't find 10th decimal digit of sqrt{2}

Tags: c

My code for finding 10th decimal digit of square root of 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned long long int power(int a, int b);
unsigned long long int root(int a);
int main()
{
    int n;
    n=10;

    
    printf("%llu \n",root(n));
    
    return 0;
}

unsigned long long int power(int a, int b)
{   
    int i;
    unsigned long long int m=1;
    for (i=1;i<=b;i++)
    {
        m*=a;
    }
    return m;

}

unsigned long long int root(int a)
{
    unsigned long long int c=1;
    int counter=1;
    while(counter<=a)
    {
        c*=10;
        while(power(c,2)<=2*power(10,2*counter))
        {
            c++;
        }
        c-=1;
        counter++;
    }
    return c;

}
```

I have tried the same algorithm in python. It can find the 10th decimal digit of $sqrt{2}$ immediately.
However, while doing C, I have waited for 10 mins but without a result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does 10 digits number become 9,999,999,999?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64628285/why-does-10-digits-number-become-9-999-999-999)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Python` handles big numbers for you. [1]

Although, as you say that you are getting the answer "immediately", your algorithm in `python` is not probably the same as the one you used in `C`.

@[bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64630800/11498773)'s answer already explains why you are not getting the expected results in C.

[1] [Handling very large numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

you have  overflow(s)

when *counter* values 10 you try to compute `power(10,20)` but even *long long* on 64 bits are not enough large, so you loop in

> ```
> while(power(c,2)<=2*power(10,2*counter)){
>    c++;
>  }
> ```

for a long time (may be without ending)

Having *long long* on 64 bits allows to compute the result for *n* valuing up to 9

Answer (score 1):

Exceed the range that the data can represent. when counter is equal to 10,`2*power(10,2*counter)` exceeds the range that unsigned long long int can represent. Python supports large number calculations, unlimited digits