# Why does my character sorting program produce wrong answers?

Tags: arrays, c, function, sorting, char

I am trying to create a program in C, in which a user inserts random strings into a matrix. The program then uses this formula to evaluate each string and the rest of the code to display the string with the highest value. Every subsequent letter has a bigger value than the previous one.

I would be very glad if someone could point me in the right direction with this, currently the program displays some random letters from the strings.

Formula: `Sum=(t*26^(n-1))`

t = number of the letter, n = number of letters remaining

Example: `abc -> 1*26^2+2*26^1+3*26^0`

The rest of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void insert(int, char[10][10], int num[]);
int computing(char[10]);
void sort(int, int num[], char[10][10]);
int main(){
    int x;
    char arr[10][10];
    int num[x];
    printf("How many words do you wish to enter: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &x);
    insert(x, arr, num);
    sort(x, num, arr);
return 0;
}
void insert(int x, char arr[10][10], int num[]){
    int i, r;
    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
        printf("Insert %d. word: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &arr[i][0]);
        num[i] = computing(arr[i]);
    }
}
int computing(char arr[10]){
    int n, i, t=1, m=0, k;
    n = strlen(arr);
    k = n;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){ 
        m += (t*26^(k-1));
        t++;
        k = k - 1;
    }
return m;
}
void sort(int x, int num[], char arr[10][10]){
    int i, temp;
    char ch;
        for(i = 0; i < x - 1; i++){
            if(num[i] > num[i+1]){
                temp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[i+1];
                num[i+1] = temp;
        
                ch = arr[i][0];
                arr[i][0] = arr[i+1][0];
                arr[i+1][0] = ch;
            }
        }
    printf("Word with the biggest sum is: %s\n", &arr[x-1][0]);
}
```

Comment: Are you under the impression that the `^` operator is exponentiation (i.e., that `26^(k-1)` is raising 26 to the power of k-1)? Because it ain't ... it's an Exclusive Or (bitwise) operator.

Comment: In fact, C doesn't have an exponentiation operator. [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101439/10871073).

Comment: Also, the scanf format should be "%c" or "%1s".   The "%s" will look for multiple characters terminated by whitespace, I believe.

Comment: Note that your function `computing(char arr[10])` doesn't use any of the actual characters in the string, so all strings of the same length will have the same 'value'. The example using `"abc"` is a poor one, because it doesn't disambiguate *"t = number of the letter"*. Also, are you sure that `int` can hold this power-based value?

Comment: `int num[x];` is _above_ the `scanf(" %d",&x);` so `x` is _uninitialized_. Move the `int num[x];` _below_ the `scanf`

Comment: Your `sort` is broken. Even with the noted fixes, it corrupts an entry on test data I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

1. `^` is *not* the power function
2. `int num[x];` is above the `scanf(" %d",&x);` so `x` is uninitialized. Move the `int num[x];` below the `scanf`
3. The sort is broken. Even with the noted fixes, it corrupts an entry on test data I provided.
4. The sort needs to perform N passes over the data. As present, it only does one.
5. `arr` is hardwired at `char arr[10][10];`. It should be dynamic like `num` as: `char arr[x][10];`

It's much easier to define a `struct` that has both the word string (in `arr`) *and* its `num` score. Then, the sort doesn't have to swap *two* arrays only one.

---

So, I refactored the code to use such a `struct` and fixed the sort and the other issues. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int num;                            // ranking
    char str[10];                       // word string
} word_t;

void insert(int, word_t num[]);
int computing(word_t *);
void sort(int, word_t num[]);

int
main(void)
{
    int x;
// NOTE/BUG: x is _not_ yet initialized
#if 0
    char arr[10][10];
    int num[x];
#endif

    printf("How many words do you wish to enter: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &x);

// NOTE/FIX: x is now initialized
#if 1
    word_t words[x];
#endif

    insert(x, words);

    sort(x, words);

    return 0;
}

void
insert(int x, word_t *words)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        word_t *word = &words[i];

        printf("Insert %d. word: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", word->str);

        word->num = computing(word);
        printf("DEBUG: num=%d '%s'\n",word->num,word->str);
    }
}

int
computing(word_t *word)
{
    int n, i,
        t = 1,
        m = 0,
        k;

    n = strlen(word->str);
    k = n;

// NOTE/FIX: compute pow(26,k - 1);
#if 1
    int p26 = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= (k - 1); ++i)
        p26 *= 26;
#endif

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
#if 0
        m += (t * 26 ^ (k - 1));
#else
        m += (t * p26);
#endif
        t++;

        k = k - 1;
// NOTE/FIX: recalc pow(26,k - 1) now that we've decremented k
#if 1
        p26 /= 26;
#endif
    }

    return m;
}

void
sort(int x, word_t *words)
{
    int i;
    word_t temp;
    int more = 1;

    while (more) {
        more = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < x - 1; i++) {
            word_t *lhs = &words[i];
            word_t *rhs = &words[i + 1];

            if (lhs->num > rhs->num) {
                temp = *lhs;
                *lhs = *rhs;
                *rhs = temp;
                more = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Word with the biggest sum is: %s\n", words[x - 1].str);
}
```

---

Here is the input data I used:

```
7
abc
defg
hijkl
mnopqr
hello
world
gbye
```

Note that in the original code, the program printed out `mbye` as the answer

---

Here is the program output:

```
How many words do you wish to enter:
Insert 1. word: DEBUG: num=731 'abc'
Insert 2. word: DEBUG: num=19010 'defg'
Insert 3. word: DEBUG: num=494265 'hijkl'
Insert 4. word: DEBUG: num=12850896 'mnopqr'
Insert 5. word: DEBUG: num=494265 'hello'
Insert 6. word: DEBUG: num=494265 'world'
Insert 7. word: DEBUG: num=19010 'gbye'
Word with the biggest sum is: mnopqr
```

A possible future issue/fix. Note that the `num` value is the *same* for both `hello` and `world`. If we're going to the trouble to raise a number to a power, should these numbers be different?