# C conversion may change value

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am new in C programming and I have problem with this small code:

```
int main(){
    int score = 0;

    score = score + pow(2, 1);
    printf("%d", score);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code with **-Wconversion** I get this error:

> error: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Werror=float-conversion]

On this line:

> score = score + pow(2, 1);

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Where are your `#include`s ?

Comment: @david Cast the result explicitly to the type int.

Comment: By not using a sledgehammer to crack the nut, for powers of 2. `score = score + (1 << 1) ;` Where possible, avoid the use of `pow()` when working with integers. Please see [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by not using functions which return floating point values within integer calculations. Read up on `pow()` to find out why that applies here.
The idea to just cast the result does not solve the problem, it just hides it.
You want a calculation of integral powers, for (and relying on) a situation in which non-integral results are not in scope.

For background see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) it explains what "values may change" means.