# How can I correctly find the armstrong "value" of a number?

Tags: c, math

I'm trying to find whether a number is an armstrong number or not, but first, I want to find the armstring value (each digit of the number must be powered to the number of digits in the number).
For instance, if 9474 was the value,
we should do 9^4(4 is the number of digits in the number) + (4^4) + (7^4) + (4^4) = 9474.

Some useful facts about my code:

1. `digitcount` counts the digit to be squared
2. `b` is intended to be the armstrong value

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int b,remainder, digitcount, i, j;
    digitcount = 0;
    printf("Enter a value for i: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    b = 0;
    remainder = 1;
    while (i != 0){
        i = i/10;
        ++digitcount;
    }
    printf("%d", digitcount);
    for (j = 1; j <= digitcount; j++){
        while (i != 0){
            while (digitcount != 0){
                remainder = (i % 10)*= digitcount;
                b = b+remainder;
                i = i/10;
                digitcount--;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", b);
    
}
```

When I put in 9474 for this, my answer yields an error `"Invalid value on assignement".`

I've been trying to debug this, but to no avail.
what should I change in my code?

Comment: Once you've counted the digits what is the value of `i`? You need to save that original value to use again later. Stepping through the code in a debugger would help you understand what's happening.

Comment: I don't see how you could even get 40. `i` goes to 0 and stays there.

Comment: `printf("%d", digitcount);` prints 4, no newline, and `printf("%d", b);` prints 0. So 40

Comment: oh im sorry, I put in the wrong output since I was debugging it, I've edited my code. It yields an error btw.

Comment: code doesn't even compile

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes I've edited that in my original question. Sorry about the initial mistake

Comment: @Droid For `0`, is that 1 digit  or zero digits?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes it is 1 digit

Comment: `while (i != 0){  i = i/10;  ++digitcount;  }` should then be `do { i = i/10; ++digitcount;  } while (i != 0);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thank u for ur suggestion, however I think that portion works just fine (I will change it however based on ur suggestion), its just the second portion, the portion that attempts to find the armstrong value, which is wrong

Comment: @Droid For `-123`, is that the digits `1,2,3`, `-1,-2,-3` or what?

Comment: I will not receive any negative values as my input

Comment: `int i` allows negatives so `scanf("%d", &i);` and code does check the range.  `unsigned i` does not.

Comment: I suggest you break the problem down into smaller pieces and create functions for those. A function to count the digits in a number and another function to calculate the Nth power of a number. Then your problem is simple. Count the digits, for each digit calculate the power then add it to the result.

Answer (score 0):

> what should I change in my code?

You should break it into smaller, simpler modules. For your problem:

> *An Armstrong number is a number that is the **sum** of **its own digits** each raised to the **power** of the **number of digits**, in a given base* `b`.

You have to:

1. Calculate the number of digits of a given number.
2. Calculate the power of a given number to a given exponent.
3. Break a number into digits.
4. Calculate a sum of powers.

The first one is fairly easy to do:

```
int count_digits(int n)
{
    int ndigits = 0;
    
    while (n != 0) {
        n /= 10;
        ndigits += 1;
    }
    
    return ndigits;
}
```

The second one is done using [exponentiation by squaring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101613/16835308) (thanks @[Dúthomhas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2706707/d%c3%bathomhas)):

```
int int_pow(int base, unsigned exp)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (;;) {
        if (exp & 1)
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        if (!exp)
            break;
        base *= base;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, the third and fourth ones become more straightforward:

```
bool is_armstrong(int n)
{
    int ndigits = count_digits(n);
    int digitsum = 0;
    
    for (int i = n; i != 0; i /= 10) {
        int digit = i % 10;
        digitsum += int_pow(digit, ndigits);
    }
    
    return n == digitsum;
}
```

---

If you want to test it:

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 9474;
    printf("Armstrong(%d) = %s\n", n, is_armstrong(n) ? "true" : "false");
}
```

Prints:

```
Armstrong(9474) = true
```

Comment: [Exponentiation by squaring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101613/2706707)