# Why does casting to uint64_t change the results in this code?

Tags: c

In the following code why do the sum and cast_sum results diverge at 2^53?  The results of `pow(2, 53)` and `(uint64_6) pow(2, 53)` appear the same but when I sum them I get different results.  Overall goal was to sum the results of 2^0 through 2^63.  I just don't understand why using `pow(2, i)` fails and `(uint64_t) pow(2, i)` works.  Or why the results of the two differ starting at 2^53.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  uint64_t sum = 0;
  uint64_t cast_sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 65; ++i) {
    sum += pow(2,i);
    cast_sum += (uint64_t) pow(2,i);
    printf("i: %d, 2^%d = %lf, sum: %lu, cast_sum:%lu\n", i, i, pow(2, i), sum, cast_sum);
  }
}
```

````
i: 52, 2^52 = 4503599627370496.000000, cast of 2^52: 4503599627370496, sum: 9007199254740991, cast_sum:9007199254740991
i: 53, 2^53 = 9007199254740992.000000, cast of 2^53: 9007199254740992, sum: 18014398509481984, cast_sum:18014398509481983
i: 54, 2^54 = 18014398509481984.000000, cast of 2^54: 18014398509481984, sum: 36028797018963968, cast_sum:36028797018963967```
````

Comment: The 2^53 is no coincidence. 2^53 is the limit for which integers 64-bit floats (which have 52 mantissa bits plus one implicit bit) can accurately represent. `pow(2, i)` is a `double`, so `sum += pow(2, i)` will be doing a double addition, casting `sum` to a double and only casting it back afterwards.

Comment: The `double` has only 53 significant bits. And `pow()` is inaccurate. If you must use `pow()` for an integer result please use `round(pow())`. But for integer powers of 2 don't even use `pow()` use bit shifting. So `sum += (uint64_t)1 << i;`

Comment: As mentioned, you're mixing integer and floating point operations, and the implicit casts do not occur where you were expecting them to.  But for something like this, you shouldn't be calling `pow` at all.  Normally you'd change `pow(2, i)` to `((uint64_t) 1) << i`, but in this case `i` goes up to `64`, so you're going to overflow as soon as you try to force it to a `uint64_t`, regardless of whether you get the value from `pow` or from a left shift.

Comment: @Luatic That makes sense, thank you.  I didn't realize that sum would be cast to a double and then cast back to a uint64_t.  I though that the results of pow would be cast to a uint64_t.  If you make that an answer I will accept.  Thanks again.

Comment: @WeatherVane What should I use instead of pow()?

Comment: @TomKarzes The actual code I wrote only goes up to i = 63 and doesn't wrap around.  I upped it a bit while trying to figure things out.  You are correct that I didn't understand where the implicit casts were occurring.

Comment: @GregoryArenius Ok, so use a left shift.  As a general rule, if you should avoid using `pow` when both arguments are integers.  When raising `2` to an integer power, it's especially easy since you can use a left shift applied to `1`.  Just make sure the `1` has the same type as the desired integer result type.

Comment: And for integer powers of integers other than 2, you should have [exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int) in your toolbox.

Comment: @TomKarzes I'm coming from a Python background and just starting to learn c.  Digging in where I don't understand something.  A shift wasn't on my radar but it is now, as well as exponentiation.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @GregoryArenius Python has shift operators as well.  You don't need to use them to raise an integer `2` to some power in Python, but they're available, and you don't have to worry about integer overflow in Python.  Try the following in Python:  `2**100 == 1 << 100`.  You should get `True`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [C's implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion):

> Otherwise, if one operand is double, double complex, or double imaginary (since C99), the other operand is implicitly converted as follows:
> integer or real floating type to double

`pow(2, i)` is a double. `sum += pow(2,i);` thus converts `sum` to a double before adding; it is roughly equivalent to `sum = (uint64_t) (((double) sum) + pow(2, i));`.

The 2^53 is no coincidence. 2^53 is the limit for which integers 64-bit floats (which have 52 mantissa bits plus one implicit bit) can accurately represent. When `sum` uses more than 53 significant bits and is casted to a double, some of the less significant bits will be lost in the conversion.

If instead you cast *before* adding, all is fine since you're working in the realm of 64-bit integer addition. Note that floats, using an exponent-mantissa representation, can exactly represent even rather large powers of two. So `pow(2, i)` *can* be exact for your small `i`. This can and will then be exactly converted into the appropriate 64-bit unsigned integer.

You should use bit shifts `1ULL << i` instead of `pow(2, i)` though. Depending on how `pow` is implemented, it may not always be exact. Bitshifts will always be more reliable and more efficient.

If you want the bit pattern where all bits are ones, simply use `~0ULL`.