# while loop stop working with big numbers c#

Tags: c#, while-loop, sum, big-o, sequence

My while loop works fine with 10_000, but it takes time to load with 100_000 and doesn't work with 10_000_000.

I don't understand why, it's a machine, and it should be fast no matter the numbers. So I suppose there is a mistake in my code, but for me, everything looks good.

implementing this [image]

```
Console.WriteLine(SumSequenceElements(10_000_000));

static double SumSequenceElements(int n)
{
   int i = 1;
   double sum = 0;
   while (i <= n)
   {
      int j = 0;
      double power = 1;
      while (j < i + 1)
      {
         power *= -1;
         j++;
      }

      sum += power / (i * (i + 1));
      i++;
   }

   return sum;
}
```

Comment: "I don't understand why, it's a machine, and it should be fast no matter the numbers" - um, really not. Your code executes the inner loop roughly (n^2)/2 times. When n is 10 million, that's a *lot* of iterations.

Comment: Hint: there's a much, *much* simpler way of working out (-1)^(i+1). You really don't need to iterate i+1 times to evaluate that.

Comment: In comp sci and specifically in software engineering, the concept of computational complexity (how long something takes and how much memory it takes) as a function of its inputs is called [Big O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Your algorithm shown in your example is **O** (**n** squared). That's a computational complexity to avoid, because it makes your programs astonishingly slow for large values of **n**. This concept is worth studying.

Comment: Is this an assignment? Usually the whole point of such an assignment is for you to understand the complexity behind computations and for you to come up with a "smarter" solution. Like simplification of a formula.

Comment: "I don't understand why, it's a machine, and it should be fast no matter the numbers." - man, try logic. By your logic no one would EVER need to buy a supercomputer or a hardware upgrade because "it is a machine, it should be fast no matter the numbers". No need to ever upgrade. Real world - as you SHOULD know - does not work like that. Makes me wonder why you think people do hardware upgrades, like ever?

Comment: @Vita: "did I ask you about your thoughts", yes, you did, by asking here.... 

Comment: I asked about the loop, not about me and my knowledge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(-1)^k` is `+1` if `k` is even and `-1` if `k` is odd. Now, we have `k = i + 1`. I.e., whenever `i` is even, then `k` is odd and vice versa.
Or, in other words, `(-1)^(i+1)` is `-1` if `i` even and `+1` if `i` is odd.

You can test whether  an `int` is even by looking at the remainder of the division by 2. C#'s [Modulus operator `%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) is yielding this remainder.

```
static double SumSequenceElements(int n)
{
   int i = 1;
   double sum = 0;
   while (i <= n)
   {
      double power = i % 2 == 0 ? -1 : +1;
      sum += power / (i * (i + 1));
      i++;
   }

   return sum;
}
```

By avoiding the inner loop, the computational complexity decreases from **O(n^2)** to **O(n)**, i.e., from quadratic to linear. A made a little benchmark on my PC. With n = 1 million, both of my methods (above and below) take 2 ms to run, your method takes about 16 minutes on my PC. This is exactly the expected speed increase of 1/2 a million which corresponds to the average number of times the inner loop is running for 1 iteration of the outer loop.

Btw., `?:` is [the ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

Since the sign of this +/-1 power is switching between + and - at each iteration. You can also write:

```
static double SumSequenceElements(int n)
{
   int i = 1;
   double power = 1; // Since we start with i = 1
   double sum = 0;
   while (i <= n)
   {
      sum += power / (i * (i + 1));
      power *= -1; // Change the sign of power
      i++;
   }

   return sum;
}
```

This does the same calculation as you did, but instead of using a nested loop which starts at `power = 1` every time, we calculate it continuously in the outer loop.

`power *= -1` uses a [Compound assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator#compound-assignment) to calculate `power = power * -1`.

---

**Update:** Source of numerical errors

As part of the calculation, we compute `i * (i + 1)`. `i` is an `int` with a range of ~ -2 billions to +2 billions. We get an arithmetic overflow when i is >= 46340 (which is ~sqrt(2^31)).

There are two possibilities to fix the error:

1. Declare `i` as `long`. Works with n < ~ 3 billions ~ sqrt(2^63).
2. Calculate `i * (i + 1.0)` instead. Note that we add `1.0` instead of `1`. This switches from `int` arithmetic to `double` arithmetic with Max(double) = ~1.7 × 10^308.

Another improvement we can make is to reverse the loop. Adding small numbers to a much larger number leads to [loss of precision](https://www.soa.org/news-and-publications/newsletters/compact/2014/may/com-2014-iss51/losing-my-precision-tips-for-handling-tricky-floating-point-arithmetic/) for floating point numbers. Therefore we should start by adding the small fractions.

By using `long` and `1.0` we are not limited by the 2 billions limit for `n` and not for the ~3 billions limit for `i * (i + 1)`. My ultimate solution also uses the reversed loop for increased precision:

```cs
static double SumSequenceElements(long n)
{
    long i = n;
    double power = i % 2 == 0 ? -1 : +1;
    double sum = 0;
    while (i >= 1) {
        sum += power / (i * (i + 1.0));
        power *= -1; // Change the sign of power
        i--;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

This version is somewhat faster than the forward loop, because the loop conditions tests `i` versus the constant value `1`, where as the forward loop tests it versus the variable `n`.

Tested for n = 10,000,000,000. Result: 0.38629436111989063 in ~21.8 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, your decisions are good. Unfortunately, I have about 5 similar assignments, and there are different power numbers, not just change signs +-. And also I was told to use a while statement for raising to power. From the comments above I've  got that the inner loop will not work, so maybe I will make it outside, Idk, but thank you anyway)

Comment: Sorry, out of curiosity I tried your solutions, and it didn't work with my numbers either...

Comment: Your inner loop does work. The problem is, that it will loop in average n/2 times per outer loop. Together with the outer loop this gives n * n/2 repetitions. So for 1,000,000 you get 500,000,000,000 iterations.

Comment: My second solution uses a while loop to calculate the power. It reuses the already existing outer loop for this. But there are more efficient ways with fewer iterations to calculate the power in a loop: [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int). Btw.: My methods take 2 ms for n = 1 million, your takes 16 minutes on my PC

Comment: haha, that's why I couldn't wait for it... I tried your method, and it returns a wrong value as a sum, it's a weekend so I didn't think why. I cannot use anything else but while, especially the pow function

Comment: I found the source of the error. It is due to arithmetic overflow for large numbers. See my update in my answer.

Comment: oh, it still gives wrong due to my test expected result (10 000 000 should be 0.38629436111988125), but I already cheated by returning it without executing the program, if even here people struggle with loops, how could I do 6 tasks in 2 hours 100% correctly? thank you anyway, your solution is the best, I appreciate spending time)

Comment: Note I tested 10 billions, not 10 millions.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, but how would it help with 10 m?))

Comment: For 10 m I get 0.38629436111988125 with the forward loop and 0.38629436111988563 with the reverse loop. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%28%28%28-1%29%5E%28i%2B1%29%29%2F%28i*%28i%2B1%29%29%29+for+i+%3D+1+to+10000000) yields 0.386294361119885618835464242791 which is closer the the reverse loop version and thus confirms its higher precision. Your expected result is less precise. (Hint: click "more digits" in the WolphramAlpha link).

Answer (score 2):

*"I don't understand why, it's a machine, and it should be fast no matter the numbers"*

When checking how much time the loop is needing, you can change code to:

```
static double SumSequenceElements(int n)
{
   int i = 1;
   double sum = 0;
   DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
   while (i <= n)
   {
      if (i % 100000 == 0) {
         Console.WriteLine($"{(DateTime.Now-d).TotalSeconds:N5}: {i}");
         d=DateTime.Now;
      }
      int j = 0; //.......(rest of code unchanged)
```

Which produced output like:

```
10,66730: 100000
31,94547: 200000
53,36376: 300000
```

You can see that every step takes more time. A simple conclusion that can be drawn is that the `while (j<i+1){ ... }` is taking more time when the value of `i` is getting larger..

Feel free to do some more debugging on this to expand your knowledge on this.

Answer (score 1):

Olivier's answer is excellent, and I would advise using that, but looking at this I got curious and found a constant time approximation, detailed below.

First, the fraction 1/i(i+1) (Forgive my lack of LaTeX) is equal to 1/i + 1/(i+1) - 2/(i+1). This can be determined via [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), and confirmed by recombining the fraction. Then, the sum becomes:

1/1 + 1/2 - 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/3 + ... + (-1)^(n+1)*(1/(n+1)) - 2H_n - 1.
The first bits telescope, and all but the first and last term cancel to give:
1 + (-1)^(n+1)*(1/(n+1)) - 2H_n - 1, simplifying further to:
(-1)^(n+1)*(1/(n+1)) - 2H_n.

At this point, an approximation for the nth harmonic number (some [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4657731/approximating-harmonic-numbers-h-n-with-degree-3-polynomial-and-ln)) can be applied to whatever precision is required and the sum obtained in constant time.