# Calculating the Number of Ways to Prepare Cereal Bowls for N People with Milk First (Algorithm Request)

Tags: c, algorithm, math, combinatorics

I was given the following:

Rigel is a cereal lover and a massive philanthropist. Every day he has N numbers of people that
he needs to feed. As a cereal lover, He wants to spread his love for cereal so he opens a pantry that
serves cereal to people in need. The pantry has N bowls and always stocks N different types of cereal
and N different types of milk in his possession. Each type of milk and cereal is stocked every day to
serve only one person. Rigel realized if he kept doing the same thing over and over again, he would
eventually get bored. So he changes the way he prepares the cereals every day. Note that Rigel is a
firm believer in Milk First Theory and despises anyone who says Cereal First is the correct way. So
when there's an empty bowl he will always pour in the milk first. Given N many people can you
calculate the number of different ways Rigel can prepare the cereal bowls?
Note: If the output is more than or equal to 10<sup>9</sup> + 7, take the modulo by 10<sup>9</sup> + 7

**Input**
The program will ask for a single input, which is N

**Output**
Print the number of different ways Rigel can prepare cereals.

Examples:

```
input: 1    output: 1
input: 2    output: 24
input: 3    output: 3240
```

I tried to solve it with the following method:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    long long int n;
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    long long int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        result = 1;
        if (i == 1)
        {
            result = 1;
        }else{
        result = result * (i*i) * (pow(6, i-1) * pow(10, i-2));
        }
    }
    printf("%lld\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

yes for the 3 inputs it worked but those are the only test cases, so I submitted the program and it wasn't accepted. Personally I think my mistake is in the algorithm for finding the number, I was hopping somebody could help me solve this problem.

Comment: Whatever "competition" or "judge" site you're using, does it tell you the input that fails? Then hard-code that input into your programs, build and [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) locally on your own system. Otherwise use its forums to help you.

Comment: By the way, you should not use the floating point `pow` function for integer powers.

Comment: I don't see any modulo in the code, so I'd guess it's about large numbers since it is explicitly mentioned in the note.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the judge does not give me the input that fails it only gave me the score which I got 20/100,  so what do you recommend I use to replace the pow function

Comment: at the begining of your loop you have `result = 1;`. You're overwritting the result at each iteration

Comment: @Cid yes I did that on purpose and for every test case given the output was as expected but I was only given 3 test cases and the judge does not tell me my mistakes

Comment: @Cid sorry just realized the for loop was pointless and just deleted it

Comment: Could you explain why N = 2 gives 24? If there are 2 bowls, cereals, milks, and people, then shouldn't it be 2^4 = 16?

Comment: @SimonGoater that is exactly why I'm confused, In the method I used to solve it i fully relied on trying to find the n umber patern

Comment: @JasonChristian Then I suggest you ask the poser of the question. Understanding where the example numbers come from must come before coding a general solution.

Comment: They can't share the same bowl and they can't have the same milk. They can have the same cereals tho

Comment: @Cid 'Each type of milk and cereal is stocked every day to serve only one person'

Comment: @SimonGoater the question is from my university and I don't exactly know who to ask since these questions are probably written by students too

Comment: In fact, since it doesn't say anything about the order in which the people are served their cereal, N=2 could be just 8. Bad question methinks. I'd move on to a more well defined problem then.

Comment: @SimonGoater I completely agree, I wish I could just do that but this would affect my score and there is a chance that the question is completely wrong since no one has finished it

Comment: @JasonChristian: What is ଽ?

Comment: To get to 24 for N=2, there may be some ordering issue. E.g., preparing a bowl, milk, cereal, then a bowl, milk, cereal may be different from preparing a bowl, milk, a bowl, milk, cereal, and cereal. However, I do not see a designation of distinctions that produces 24 as an answer. Completely distinguishing items by which person they are going to produces 12 orders (e.g., B0 M0 C0 B0 M1 C1, B0 B1 M1 M0 C0 C1, etc.), but then multiplying by the choices of bowls, milks, and cereals multiplies that by 2^3, making 96. Incompletely distinguishing does not produce a multiple of 3 needed for the 24.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, ଽ probably means e from mantissa-exponent notation, so it's 10e+7.

Comment: What is more efficient than `pow` (and gives an exact answer) is exponentiation. See [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int). You'll need to apply the modulo after every arithmetic operation (using `long long` to give headroom), or a 'fail' is inevitable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the ଽ is just supposed to be power of 9 I don't know how it turned that way after a pasted it

Answer (score 1):

Rigel can start with any person, P1 to PN and give them a bowl and milk (milk is always first, and all bowls are the same). He can then either give the same person cereal, or another person a bowl and milk, and so on until all people have bowl, milk and cereal.  He can never give cereal before bowl and milk.

For N=2, possible orders are

```
p1m1 p1c1 p2m2 p2c2
p1m1 p2m2 p1c1 p2c2
p1m1 p2m2 p2c2 p1c1
```

multipled by the 8 combinations of p,m,c this gives 24.

For any N, this is related to the paths through an NxNxN cube where the path can only go in increasing steps on the x, y and z axes.  I assume there is a closed form solution.

Comment: But I don't think this explains how an input of 3 can give you 3240

Comment: A person isn't an ingredient, right? And the order is always bowl, milk, cereal. Therefore, the number of combinations is N^3? To be honest, I find this question a bit unclear on the details.

Comment: @BasVisscher There's no real difference between lining up the bowls or the persons (persons are probably easier to distinguish though). The number of combinations is N!^3. But I agree that the question requires a lot of re-reading.

Comment: @JasonChristian It does, but the explanation is somewhat longer, which is why I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

There are N! ways to line up the people and the same is true for the types of milk and types of cereals. That makes N!^3 combinations. (In case N = 2, that would be 8, in case N = 3, that would be 216).

stark (the first one who answered) already listed the 3 possible orders for N = 2.

The possible orders for N = 3 are:

```
p1m p1c p2m p2c p3m p3c
p1m p1c p2m p3m p2c p3c
p1m p1c p2m p3m p3c p2c
p1m p2m p2c p3m p3c p1c
p1m p2m p2c p3m p1c p3c
p1m p2m p2c p1c p3m p3c
p1m p2m p1c p2c p3m p3c
p1m p2m p1c p3m p2c p3c
p1m p2m p1c p3m p3c p2c
p1m p2m p3m p1c p2c p3c
p1m p2m p3m p1c p3c p2c
p1m p2m p3m p2c p1c p3c
p1m p2m p3m p2c p3c p1c
p1m p2m p3m p3c p1c p2c
p1m p2m p3m p3c p2c p1c
```

Note that the order of the persons is covered by lining up the people in N! ways, hence the strict order of p1, p2 and p3. And since the type of milk and cereals were already chosen, I didn't bother to number them as well.

Now 15 * 216 = 3240.

The only issue remaining is to find a nice closed expression for the possible orders.

---

Addition:
For N = 1 there's only one possible order to add milk and cereals. Note there are 2 actions to perform.

If another bowl is added as the first bowl, adding the cereals can take place before, during or after preparing the second bowl. This gives us the 3 possible orders for N = 2.

Adding more bowls continues this pattern.
Therefor the total possible orders is 3 * 5 * ... * (2N - 1)

Comment: let me try to find a closed expression, thanks for the help

Comment: could the closed expression be N!^3 * 3 * 5**(n-2)

Comment: @JasonChristian For N=2, we have 4 actions. Hence, if we add a bowl (as no 1), adding the cereals can happen at 5 places. So we end up with 5 * 3 possible orders. If we yet add another bowl, we'll end up with 7 * 5 * 3 possible orders. And so on. (And for N=1 there were 2 actions. Adding a bowl gives us the 3 possible orders we found for N=2). In TeX I'd write: Number of possible orders is $\Pi_{n=1}^{N-1} (2n+1}$. (multiplication of all odd numbers from 3 to 2N-1).