# compiling issue wirh a c progarm

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, compilation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        j = pow(i, 2);
        printf("the square of %d is %d\n", i, j);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*when i run this program in vscode it gives me this results in terminal : *

```
the square of 0 is 0
the square of 1 is 1
the square of 2 is 4
the square of 3 is 9
the square of 4 is 16
the square of 5 is 24
the square of 6 is 36
the square of 7 is 49
the square of 8 is 64
the square of 9 is 81
the square of 10 is 99
```

*now notice that 5 and 10 squared are not correct.
when i asked gpt it says that pow should turn double not int and when i do so the program runs perfectly, the problem here is that the first program deos not generate an error so the problem is in the compiler itself, matter of fact when i run the program in an online c compiler it gives me these results :*

```
the square of 0 is 0
the square of 1 is 1
the square of 2 is 4
the square of 3 is 9
the square of 4 is 16
the square of 5 is 25
the square of 6 is 36
the square of 7 is 49
the square of 8 is 64
the square of 9 is 81
the square of 10 is 100
```

*now notice that the values are correct

in summery how do i fix this problem ????*

i think i explained all

Comment: My hunch is that your program is flooring a floating point value down to an integer instead of rounding because your variable is integer. This is because floats are more like values that have a resolution, where integers are more concrete. Following this a float(double) is like a recorded video while int is more like actually being there.

Technically your code compiles just fine, this is a programmer error.

Comment: `-Wconversion -Werror`. You now have a compilation error.

Comment: At the very least, see [Is floating-point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/15168) — that might be a suitable duplicate (but see the discussion on [Meta Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427530/15168)).  Basically, floating-point arithmetic involves approximations, and using `pow()` to do integer arithmetic can lead to errors of the sort you see.  Consquently, it is a bad idea to use the floating-point functions like `pow()` when dealing with integers, especially when the calculation is as simple as `i * i` in integer notation.

Comment: If you really must use `pow()` for integer calculations, then do `int y = (int)round(pow(x, n));`. But generally, don't. Use exponentiation, [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)

Answer (score 2):

Change `j = pow(i, 2);` to `j = i*i;` to use only integer arithmetic.

`pow` is a floating-point function. It should produce an exact result when an exact result is representable, but low-quality implementations produce approximations, such as 99.9999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375 for `pow(10, 2)`.

When the `double` value 99.9999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375 is converted to `int` for assignment to `j`, it is truncated to 99.

When you calculate `i*i`, the product will be computed with integer arithmetic, and there will be no approximation. (However, integer arithmetic will overflow when the values exceeds the bounds of what the type can represent.)

Comment: Another danger is getting a floating point result slightly _above_ the expected result. It'll truncate to the expected int value and look like it's worked properly, and the bug will go unnoticed. If the OP had only run in the online compiler, this would have happened.