Is there inlinable function for pow2?
Does C++ std have some inlinable template for pow2 (square) which will work efficiently for all POD types?
I see that we have std::pow, std::powf, std::powl, but:

I can't be quite sure that every compiler will inline them. More that that I am sure that in Debug mode most of them won't. (MSVC won't even in Release).
These tree works with float, double and long double, while sometimes I need it for int and std::size_t.

(I have these squaring in time-critical sections of code (calculating distances between many objects, etc.) and optimal generated code is important. At the same time, arguments sometimes are long in writing and I don't wont to duplicate them in-place.)
Of course, I can write:
template <typename T>
T pow2(T v) {
    return v*v;
}

But:

I don't want to reinvent a wheel even for such tiny pieces of code if something already exists and recommended for use.
I am not sure that it will be most effective code in all cases.

And, at the end of the day, if we don't have this in the std, why and if "because pow2 is a very special case", why do we have std::pow only for floating-point types? Am I the only person who needs pow2 for integral types?

inline is only ever a suggestion.  It's a feature of the language but it is not mandated to be done in any case.

For integral types, it might overflow easily, and that is (was?) UB if signed? constexpr might help if you pow compile time numbers. But, why do you need it at all? It this really the only performance bottleneck you have? Lucky guy..

Multiply is a single fast instruction on all modern computers. I can't imagine that any other algorithm could improve on the trivial one.

I'm pretty sure it's an FAQ as to why there is no pow for integers. Try a search on this site. As I recall, it boils down to there being a rather small set of inputs for which there's no overflow, and that most of them are handled better by a shift, or one or two multiplies.

if you want fast integer powers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int

"MSVC won't even in Release"
Seems like MSVC and gcc both inline the template. https://godbolt.org/z/WaPasnjq5

"I can't be quite sure that every compiler will inline them" I don't think there is any portable way to force every compiler to inline something.

@NathanOliver, I know this for sure and this is exactly my point. That's why I used term "inlinable", not "inline". I want to have the best chance to generate optimal asm code at the place and I assume that in most cases inline would win. Anyway, what you meant with your comment? How my text in question contradicts to this statement? Do I miss the key point?

@ThomasWeller, not at all, but replacing with call to pow with conversion to float and making calls to possibly expensive library function which calculates any power will make it expensive. So, I have to write this template and my question was just if I reinvent the wheel and we have something ready. This is not only about integral types; for floating-point types specialized function for power 2 only should work faster. And, yes, impact is significant. Of course, this is not the only bottleneck, but others are not so easy taken fruits, so one at a time.

Let the compiler make that choice for you.  They are pretty good at it.  If, after you profile your optimized build, you are still not happy with the performance then you can look into doing other things but trying to optimize without data is like throwing darts at a dartboard while blindfolded.

@NateEldredge, well, I 99% agree with you. And one percent for dark waters of specific compiler optimizations. Anyway, my key point if we have something ready to avoid writing this code.

@NateEldredge, overflow makes sense, although for x64 being able to pow2 numbers up to 4*10^9 is not very small area of application. Again, I am focused on pow2 only.

@NathanOliver, thank you for the link to the integer powers, it helps. At the same time, most likely I made the wrong stress, I am interested in pow2 for all POD types, including integral types, I am not focusing on them.

@FrançoisAndrieux, thank you for the input, but it seems that you missed my point. My sentence about inlining was about library functions std::pow, std::powf, std::powl (see my question). Of course, my template will inline in 99% cases in Release. For sure, I know that inline is just a recommendation that's why I used the word "inlineable" which means that I want a better chance for compiler to inline it. On the MSVC chance of inlining the code of standard library functions is 1% and chance of inlining my code is 99%, that was my point above.

@NathanOliver, are you sure that standard library functions have a chance to be inlined with MSVC and do you really think general-purpose pow function can be similar performance as specific pow2 function? With this I mean I have two points here: (1) general-purpose function with possible type conversion would have performance impact and (2) std::pow functions most likely won't be inlined which might have some impact. I am focused on the first in this question. Again, my function works just fine, I just wanted to double-check that I am not reinventing the wheel.

If this is performance-critical, don't be afraid of reinventing wheels. Sometimes you'll need to step out and put chains on your wheels to not get stuck in snow. There shouldn't be too many performance-critical spots. As for lack of any int square function, it's an awkward spot when relying on library functions but it is how it is, just use your generic snippet and watch out for overflow.

Whether or not the standard library implements a function in such a way that it can be inlined (whether with or without LTO) is completely a decision of the implementation.
Nothing in the standard is concerned with implementation details such as optimizations and whether or not they can be applied. The standard only describes observable behavior of programs. In particular there are no performance guarantees except for asymptotic complexity of certain library functions in terms of input length.
Nothing prevents the implementation to define std::pow as inline in a header, nor does an implementation need to define the different overloads mentioned in the standard as such. The implementation could for example define std::pow as a single function template (in a header or via explicit specialization somewhere else).
But none of this is really relevant for what you want. std::pow operates on two floating point arguments. It must be written to support the power calculation for all floating point exponents. An algorithm for general powers will be much much slower than simply multiplying two values as required for a square function.
Of course, an implementation could test for the argument to be exactly 2 and branch to a simpler implementation for that special case, but I doubt they actually do given the intended use of the power function and even if they did, that is still an extra branch that is costly relative to the single multiplication.
In any case, this implementation detail of std::pow is much more important than whether the function is implemented in such a way that it can be inlined.

There is no specific square function in the standard library. You will need to write your own, for example as you have shown. This is true if performance is even remotely important, but also if accuracy of the result is important, because std::pow (in contrast to simple multiplication) does not make any guarantees on the accuracy of the result in general.

My guess as to why std::pow is in the library, but no function for squaring or general integer powers is that a correct algorithm for std::pow is much more difficult to implement and depends stronger on architecture. A decent squaring function is easy to write by hand.
Also, a power function operating purely on integer types isn't all that useful, because the result will only be representable for small range of input values. Already power-of-two can easily overflow and often requires specific handling of these cases.


Am I the only person who needs pow2 for integral types?

It is really rare that I come across a situation where this is needed outside of compile-time constants and in these situations, simply writing a multiplication is usually fine.
For floating point operations this is a bit different because longer mathematical expressions containing multiple squaring operations sometimes make sense. Sometimes it doesn't make sense to give intermediate results names so that * can be used efficiently instead and sometimes it is important to not store the result in a variable for extended precision or contracting of intermediate results. (Although the latter requires a macro instead of a function.)

Thank you for the comprehensive answer. Let me wait a day before accepting it in case of better answers, as recommended here.  One question, if you need pow2 for floating point values in many places in your code, which approach would you use?

@DamirTenishev The one you mentioned. Put that function template in a header and namespace and you should be good to go. As I mentioned in the answer, there are some specific cases where using a function at all is unfortunately limiting, e.g. if you have an expression such as pow2(x)+y where the compiler could apply floating point contraction with an fma instruction without the function call. There is nothing that can be done about this except using a macro or writing out the multiplication instead.

@DamirTenishev Maybe for a small adjustment I would replace the parameter by a const reference and the return value by auto. That way you generalize the function even to types where * doesn't return the same type and even if the type is not copyable. And probably it should also be constexpr and noexcept(noexcept(auto(v*v))).

Thank you. I am not sure about const ref, since I use it for POD types only, so no problems with being copyable, but would it be efficient to use refs for POD types? Won’t it be counter-productive? Will the compiler be always able to replace ref with plain data passing it without creating underlying pointer (even when inlining)? Abd sorry, I missed the point regarding syntax noexcept(noexcept(auto(v*v))) is it a “miscopy” or intended one? I see the following syntax: demo; which way would you change it to make noexcept(noexcept(auto(v*v)))?


I don't want to reinvent a wheel even for such tiny pieces of code if something already exists and recommended for use

There is no standard "square" function that exists and is recommended.

I am not sure that it will be most effective code in all cases

Native multiplication of built-in types is the sort of thing optimizers should be good at handling. You should assume it will be well-optimized until profiling shows otherwise.
If you do write your proposed template, it even gives you a natural customisation point in case this turns out to be untrue for some type.

And, at the end of the day, if we don't have this in the std, why

Things tend to be in the standard because they're both very widely used and easy to implement inefficiently or incorrectly. Squaring an arithmetic primitive isn't either.
Handling non-integer and non-positive powers is much more complicated.
As an aside, I encourage you not to call your function pow2 - it looks too much like exp2, which seems likely to cause confusion.

I decided to stay with sq as abbreviation from square and familiar std::sqrt. How do you feel about this name? Thank you for your input. (I was in two mind which one to accept, yours is short and precise and another one is more detailed and was published first, so I used this reasons for accepting; otherwise I would have accepted your one).

sq sounds fine to me, I agree it's consistent with sqrt.
